# Experiential audit of [rules-as-written], please?

Tags: discussion, rules-as-written

So, I've been noticing a trend on [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) lately. Mainly, people realising that "rules" is banned, so they use the first tag that starts with rules which, y'know, says *rules* on it.

This is [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) which, while quite *related* to rules, isn't.

I've also been noticing that our user community isn't really bothering to address these potential discrepancies in comments.

So, a question to each of you all. On a brief review of the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written), how many of those questions, do you believe, intended to just use it as the [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) tag? Examples would be delightful.

Useful sorting categories (add more to your answer if you have a better ontology):

- Absolutely incorrect. They used this tag as a "rules" tag
- Absolutely correct. There is evidence in the question that they really are interested in RAW
- Questionable, but we didn't comment on the question. Why didn't we?
- Questionable, but we did comment (and the user didn't respond)

To be very clear, this is a function of your interpretation as reader, based on how well they signaled their intent. If their intent is unclear *that itself* is interesting.

Comment: In a lot of cases this comes down to user intent, which isn't something we can easily determine. For example, [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51157/15469) *could* have been tagged with rules-as-written when the querent actually meant something more along the lines of rules-clarification, or they might have been trying to disallow answers along the lines of "It's unclear, but here's how I would do it/have done it." Without a statement from the user we're basically just guessing what they meant.

Comment: Yes. But that's what I'm interested in. "Class: obviously wrong. Class: we should have left a comment. Class: we did leave a comment, but user hasn't responded. Class: absolutely correct"

Comment: Fair enough, if you haven't got any answers by the time I get home I'll have a go.

Comment: What @Miniman points out is why I brought up my concern about us making assumptions about the meaning of this tag: people regularly use it without explaining _why_ they're using it.

Comment: Yes. But since we're approaching this as "people likely to answer the question" this is a hermeneutic reading of "do we *perceive* that they used the tag in a useful way?

Comment: I'm very much feeling like [rules-as-written] is a meta tag. One with quite a lot of value, but still a meta tag. I don't know how those two considerations balance out, but I think its meta-ness can no longer be ignored and should be accounted for in any discussion of the tag regardless of whether we intend to keep it. (Needing to know asker intent to understand if it's being applied right is very much a mark of a meta tag, which is why it's relevant here.)

Comment: Im not worried about its meta tag ness so much as its "being used as a rules tag"

Comment: How much are you actually noticing this? I hear a lot of stuff from experienced users claiming that it's (potentially) being misused, but I see very little evidence of it actually happening. I support a more thorough audit, but I feel like your introduction has biased things inappropriately.

Comment: I notice that a at least once a week, newish users tend to use [tag:rules-as-written] instead of the banned [tag:rules] (and then I edit the tag out). And I'm interested in how many times I miss that. I'm not trying to draw out the "do we want a meta tag" debate. I'm just "how many of these uses actually are [tag:rules-as-written] instead of [tag:rules].

Comment: And how do you determine that they're using the tag without intending it?

Comment: Well, I ask them if their question is unclear and/or if they're low rep. That's why I posed the question, to see if anyone else is getting this impression of mis-matched intentions.

Comment: Is there a source for the reasoning behind banning the rules tag for those who aren't familiar with that decision or the distinction between rules and rules-as-written?

Answer (score 6):

You know, this made me think for a while. This answer may not be what you asked for, but I hope help people think about this, even if a tangential way.

I checked a bunch of questions around the site. Most of the time, like [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51477/is-a-bluff-check-necessary-when-telling-the-truth), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51040/can-i-choose-to-grant-combat-advantage) or [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51459/how-does-shaking-off-hold-person-work), the question seems to be *about* the rules, without the need to *completely stick to the rules as published*. Those questions are more about how to proceed in a given situation (be it RAW or by some interpretation) than really using the literal text from the books.

Questions that are "Truly RAW" are a bit different. [Are humans living creatures? By the rules, that is?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51349/are-humans-living-creatures-by-the-rules-that-is) is an example - the querent explicitly rules out anything that is not written on the books - it's about how rules, as written, interact with other and what happens from there. [My question about Night Elves and Volcanos](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/can-a-night-elf-swim-naked-in-a-volcano) is also a "Truly RAW" question, despite not having the tag.  It is not about how to rule a given situation, is about what happens if you take the book literally. [This question from KRyan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39535/skill-to-recognize-cleric-domains-and-what-spells-appear-on-them) is, maybe, one of the best examples of what I would consider a good use of the Rules-as-Written tag: he explicity says that he *doesn't* want non-published material and what he already researched, and  his question is about *finding* a set of rules for a given situation and how them would work.

The thing with Rules-as-Written is that it is a tricky subject. You need to make clear what is ok and what is not on your question if you want useful RAW answers. RAW could be Core-only, Core-Plus-Splatbooks, Core-Plus-Splatbooks-Minus-Rules-Compendium, Core-Plus-Splatbooks-Minus-Tome-Of-Battle-Cause-My-DM-is-Crazy, Core-Plus-Splatbooks-Plus-Magazines, etc, etc, etc. And that's only for D&D. What, exactly, would be RAW for games that are massively subjective? Or for games that have a WTFazillion of modular, non-exclusive splatbooks, like GURPS?

Heck, some DM's even consider  Flavor Text as *rules*. They are written on the book, aren't they? This whole thing of "Rules as Written" is, ironically, pretty subjective.

So, people that *really* want a by-the-book answer will say that out loud in the question, citing what is the valid material that could be referenced. Most of the time, however, our users are mostly interested in figuring how to use the rules in a given game.

So... What I see, from my random browsing, is that what is really happening is that people are often just asking "rules clarification" questions — a sister to RAW questions, but with lesser constraints, where new users are basically saying, "Hey, I need help understanding this set of rules!" I know that this behavior is supposed to be the SE's default, but most of newcomers are not aware of that and tag away with [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written).

---

Moar audits!

- This one seems to be wanting a house-rule, not a RAW answer. The asker explicitly says that the RAW, as it is, is not enough, and wants a solution for that. The accepted answer is, indeed, a house-rule. The questioner however commented this:

  > I added the rules-as-written tag to the question to indicate that I
  >   prefer solutions which can be applied consistently with little
  >   interpretation necessary

  Which made me unsure if *this* is a use case for RAW or not. To me, it is a case of house rules, not RAW.
- [Is the product of the Heavens Mystery revelation "Coat of Many Stars" a valid target for Magic Vestment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48015/) and [Does an Enhancement bonus on clothing become an Armor bonus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48071/) are, because they are by-the-book clarifications, indeed RAW.
- [How can I keep the Tarrasque "dead"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31895/) explicitly asks for RAW, so, it is, indeed, a RAW question.
- [Can the heal spell (and other positive energy effects) work on constructs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/) wants to find a rule to a given situation, and the querent explicitly asks for RAW, so it's ok to tag as such.
- [When exactly do "once each round" effects work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21755/) wants answers *supported* by the rules. This is different from RAW, mind you, since RAI can be argued to be "supported by the rules", too. I would tag this one with Rules Clarifications, not RAW, since RAW is about taking rules *literally*. This question would welcome RAI, I think.
- [Can you intentionally fail a skill check?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49312/) uses RAW for defining the preference for a given set of rules but, in their own word, they are not mandatory. I would just remove the tag here - you don't need to tag something as RAW if it is just your preference, you can just spell it out on the question. RAW questions should be about taking the book literally.
- [Master of Shrouds Summon Undead caster level](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22499/) is explicity a Rules Clarification question, that seems tagged RAW because of the lack of a more appropriate "Rules Clarification" tag.
- [Does the rider need to expend an action to ride a horse?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51316/) is a RAW question, and it says so out loud on the last line. *It could be* a rules-clarification question, easily.
- [Are there rules for called shots in D&D 4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50728/) is *not* a RAW question. This question is asking for rules *or ideas* about how to deal with this, there is no apparent need for a by-the-book answer. The tag was not even part of the original question, and was added later, by another user.

---

I will expand the first 3 questions, to explain why I think they are not RAW.

- [Is a Bluff check necessary when telling the truth?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51477/is-a-bluff-check-necessary-when-telling-the-truth) - I think this is not a RAW question. Here, we are not dealing with rules interactions. We have the explicit aknowledgement that this may be the case of DM-Fiat, and this question is not about some strange, bizarre use of the Bluff Skill. To me, this is just a [rule-clarification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-clarification), and not a [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) case.
- [Can I choose to grant Combat Advantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51040/can-i-choose-to-grant-combat-advantage) - This one is a bit problematic. At first, I don't see any evidence that this question should be using the RAW tag, however I don't know what exactly happened on comments and, by what SevenSidedDie said on comments below, this question appears to be an exception and not representative to the question at hand.
- [How does shaking off hold person work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51459/how-does-shaking-off-hold-person-work) - This is just a rules clarification question. There is no aparent need for the RAW tag, and the user is indeed a new user, so he may not be aware of what exactly RAW means on the context of this community. This appears to be a [rule-clarification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-clarification) case.

Comment: Re observations: this is the impression I've been getting too: questions merely *about* the rules have been getting the RAW tag, which is a misuse.

Comment: Re the proposed solution: I think it might work. [rules-clarification] would get (properly) less used than the old-bad [rules] tag. Right now minimal tagging for a rules-clarification question is just a bare system tag, which is *okay*... but maybe not ideal? Such a tag would definitely catch the users who are hypothetically misusing [raw], yet do so **without decreasing the usefulness of [rules-as-written]**. That's worth at least a trial run, I think!

Comment: Could you withhold a proposed solution and stick to just the audit, so that I can vote for the usefulness of your audit _without_ also having to implicitly vote for a particular solution? Putting both together muddies the voting.

Comment: Why do you think question two and three are misusing the RAW tag?

Comment: That's a good point @doppelgreener makes; observations might be agreed with, but acting on changing the situation is a different kettle of fish that should be voted on separately if it gets to that. I've cut out the proposed solution for now. It can be dug out of the edit history should a meta be opened in that direction later. I kept some of the text as it relates to observations & impressions — how does it look?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, It looks good, indeed. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: I completely disagree with your assertion that any of these appear to be misused. They might be misused, it's conceivable, but the fact that all two of the three have accepted answers that discuss the RAW suggests, *probably not,* at least for those questions. Particularly [the one about Combat Advantage](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51040/4563), which accepted the only answer to actually cite the rules, despite the higher-rated answers that failed to do so.

Comment: @KRyan Using RAW to answer a non-RAW-Exclusive question is fine. So is using RAI. That's okay. Is not citing rules that makes a RAW question or answer, is deliberadly adhering **only** to it. Those questions are rule clarifications, not a study on how the rules, as exactly written, affect the game. RAW have more constraints than what is needed to answer those questions.

Comment: @KRyan Also, both accept answers are not RAW answers. The 4e question is explicity a DM-Fiat suggestion, and the Bluff one is about DM reasoning. The other one is not accepted. I don't see from where your reasoning is comming. Discussing RAW is one thing, answering RAW is a different matter.

Comment: Both of those cases are situations where the answer turned out to be that RAW doesn't really cover the situation. That doesn't make the *question* any less interested in the RAW. Both answers make a point of discussing the RAW *and its deficiencies,* which is valid per challenging-the-frame. This is done because the RAW isn't helpful. But the question-asker, since he did not know the answer, couldn't have known that when he chose the tag. I see no evidence that the question-asker made a mistake. And I think it's really poor form to assume that they did.

Comment: @KRyan I don't know what to say anymore. I will just retire from this discussion.

Comment: The first and second examples appear to be correctly tagged with RAW (the second is *aggressively* tagged RAW, based on my memory of its comment history). The last does look like it fits this answer's working definition of a mistag—it's a rules clarification request on its face, and it's a first-time user. (Whether one agrees that those criteria should qualify as a mistag is another issue layer.)

Comment: However, the second example has issues all by itself though and isn't representative of the problem we're poking at, at all. There, the asker *wants* a RAW answer that doesn't exist, because they don't like what RAW says, so tagged it with RAW and argued in comments with everyone who told them what RAW says. Then they accepted an answer that says what they want to hear despite being non-RAW. That says to me the question is mistagged by definition, but this falls under "don't edit war with the asker" so it should(?) stay tagged RAW.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Maybe, but I didn't had the comments on the second question to know that! The first question is not exactly about how. At least, I think that any question that actively aknowledges that there are chances of the solution being only DM-Fiat is not a RAW question. It is a *Rules Clarification*, since there is the chance to be unable to cite a source. I will fetch more questions to put on this answer.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks for the edit, I wasn't aware that RPG.SE had that feature. Way better now!

Comment: @Thales me neither until a while ago; I discovered it totally by accident. Works with plain copy+paste of the URL or with the share link of questions, can work cross-site, and I think maybe it does not work for answer share links.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What do you think of this analysis?

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk I think your first bullet is missing its link. :)

Comment: Much better researched with the additional examples.  I still disagree with your analysis of two of the first three, though, as per KRyan.

Comment: RAI is impossible to provide barring explicit statements by the authors of the work, which are rarely available. “I assume the way I want the rule to work is the way the authors wanted it to work” is **never** an acceptable answer, to **any** question, really. “The rules don’t quite say this, but it’s reasonable in my opinion and works well in my experience” is a good answer, but not for a RAW-tagged question. Assuming that someone misused the RAW tag based on “supported by the rules” is absurd; I would assume that the use of the tag and that statement are intended to go together, be the same.

Comment: Per the RAW-as-preference thing, I would lean towards including the tag. In effect, they are inviting answers to challenge the frame of the question if necessary, but *only* if necessary. You still have to make a RAW-based case that it is necessary.

Comment: You assume the Master of Shrouds question is mistagged because... what, you just don’t want it to be tagged RAW? “How does this work?” combined with a RAW tag is a pretty clear indication of what the question wants. Assuming that it’s **not** what they want seems disingenuous. Give the users the benefit of the doubt. Especially as the RAW answer was accepted.

Comment: The called shots question is similar to the "once each round" question: it seems more like an invitation to challenge the frame of the question, but only after establishing the RAW or lack thereof. As for the editing by another user, one would *hope* that was done in response to (now deleted) comments.

Comment: @Kryan The thing is, I'm not against citing rules. That is must on almost every question that deal with a game system. To me, Rules-as-written seens too much tied to Rules-Lawyering, that is a specific kind of behavior regarding rules on which you take things literally. And that's okay. However, not every question that needs a clarification regarding rules is a rules-as-written question.

Comment: In short, I agree that not every question about rules clarification requires RAW answers or the RAW tag — just the ones that explicitly used the RAW tag require it and therefore RAW answers.

Comment: @KRyan The thing is, we don't have anything that resembles a rules-clarification tag that would be used in place of Rules-as-Written when RAW answers are not exactly what you need. This whole meta is *because* people are tagging too much stuff with rules as written, when they just wanted some clarification. I'm not trying to be rude or anything.

Comment: @KRyan So please, don't assume that I'm doing it because some presumption of my part. Brian invited the community to give an audit on those questions, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @KRyan Being hostile to the concept of RAI is valid grounds for rejecting an analysis, but people who don't share such hostility to the concept of RAI are unlikely to agree with such a rejection. FYI. And I realise that's frustrating, because it doesn't compute, but that's just how mismatches of fundamental axioms or paradigms work and there is no escape or relief from being baffled by or frustrated with people operating in an alien but equally-valid paradigm.

Comment: @KRyan Also, we cannot assume that askers, especially new users, understand the concept of challenging the frame and are constructing their questions to include invitations to challenge the frame. It took the regulars here years to construct the concept; it is not an intuitive one that can be read into the average new-user question tagged [rules-as-written].

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Regarding RAI, I take the term at face-value, to mean what it says, and it is **exceptionally rare that someone can back up a claim of RAI.** I am not even rejecting the value of the author's intent: I am rejecting the notion that we can **accurately state what the RAI is** in the overwhelming majority of cases. Those few cases where it can be backed up, I don't have a problem with. Those many cases where RAI is asserted without backup? Those are bad, **deceptive** answers, that assert authority they don't have and mislead users.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't mean that they were explicitly referencing the meta question; I mean they were suggesting behavior quite similar to what we've come up with as the general meta suggestion would be appropriate for their question, independently. I don't think that's much of a stretch. But I'll acknowledge that those questions are dubious and get into what tagging is supposed to mean and such. I suspect when this is over, there should probably be a separate discussion of those kinds of questions.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, I can see that. I've had a "come to Jesus" moment though and I've suddenly reversed my displeasure with the [rules-as-written] tag in a way that makes all this kinda moot. I think it might not click with you right away, but I think if you give it some time to grow on you, we might be able to stand together to make [rules-as-written] into the exemplary tag it should be: [We've made rules-as-written sick, but we can cure it.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/the-rules-as-written-tag-is-a-good-tag-but-weve-made-it-sick-lets-cure-it)

Answer (score 3):

## Experiential audit of the Experiential audit of [rules-as-written]

Repetition intentional.

I see a lot of questions being listed as misuses, based on the idea that they are rule-clarification type questions. **That alone is insufficient to conclude that a question has been mistagged.**

A person can ask for a clarification of the rules without the RAW tag, and RAW does not mean rules-clarification. That said, they also *can* ask a rules-clarification question with the RAW tag; that is a valid and meaningful choice.

With no more information than that, **you have to assume that they intended to do what they did.** Didn’t tag with RAW? Must be interested in answers not necessarily out of the rules. Did tag with RAW? Must not be, must want everything to be by the book.

Only when you get someone tagging RAW, but asking after houserules, suggestions, and the like, or commenting that answers are too legalistic, should there be reason to start suspecting they acted in error. On the flip side, someone not tagging RAW, but then commenting on answers asking after book citations, is also someone you should suspect made a mistake.

But don’t assume there *was* a mistake just because there *could* have been a mistake. For all you know, the tagging could have been quite intentional. In fact, considering that they explicitly went and tagged it, the safer assumption is that it was. You don’t know what they want better than they do.

Comment: I've deleted my answer.

Comment: No, I don't mind at all. No problem

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk If you'd care to [join me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19179/experiential-audit-of-rules-as-written-chat)

Comment: Here's the problem with this analysis: our RAW tag is ***special***. It has special rules. It is a weird exception. You, equally, cannot assume that someone new to the site is intending to invoke those special site rules. That is the source of everyone else's problem with the tag. If it wasn't a tag with special site rules attached to it, nobody would care if it was being accidentally used wrong. But it does, and so it matters, because if it's being misused, it's actively impairing our ability to help them with their *actual* problem.

Comment: So here's the situation: if we assume they meant it, we must assume they mean to invoke the tag's special treatment. If we assume they didn't mean it, we have to assume they misunderstood the tag's purpose. **Both are assumptions that have no justification.** Hence: how do we fix that? We can't pick one or the other, because both are invalid assumptions to make. So something's gotta change so that we can move forward. The alternative is this coming up all over again next time that unacceptable situation causes a problem.

Comment: The justification is that they chose the tag and have taken no actions that indicate they didn't mean to. The justification is that they are human being who, it should be assumed, know what they want better than you do. The justification is that we should not assume people are too incompetent to use the site. The justification is that your null hypothesis that they are mistakenly using the tag unless someone proves otherwise is presumptuous and disrespectful.

Comment: Which would be fine, if we knew they knew that the tag has special rules; but they're new, so we know they don't know. Because of the special rules right there in the tag wiki, there is no null hypothesis, only two competing non-null hypotheses. Hence, the special rules must burn to restore the tag to non-meta-ness, so we can stop worrying/arguing about how people use or misuse the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What about assuming they meant it and making sure that the concerns implied by the tag are addressed, but _not penalizing people who answer from other angles, so long as at least one answer does exist with RAW citations etc._? Particularly in cases where the written rule itself explicitly calls for GM discretion.

Comment: @Random832 No, any “answer” to a RAW-tagged question that does not address the RAW is not answering the question, and should be downvoted. I will certainly always do so.

Comment: @KRyan The problem (and the reason I made this comment on this old meta question) is that that's not always what the person who uses the tag really wants. And in cases where a written rule _explicitly_ calls for discretion, I would say commentary on what sort of interpretation is intended is even within the literal bounds of the tag. And since the value of the site is in the whole set of answers, rather than one answer standing alone, I think considering that other answers address it is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @Random832 If it’s not what they really want, they need to edit their question. The thrust of this discussion is that a number of people here were **assuming** that people didn’t really want the RAW tag *even though they explicitly used the tag themselves and gave no indication that it was mistaken.* It is entirely possible that people can misuse the tag, but we cannot *assume* that in the absence of evidence. That runs counter to everything else on this site, not to mention basic courtesy. You or I don’t know what someone wants to ask better than they do themselves.

Comment: @Random832 Besides, it is impossible to control how people vote. No policy involving "not penalising answers" could be enforced even if we wished to make one.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top 26 recently active RAW questions 25 are 'Absolutely Correct' in my opinion and [1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37803/is-dd-4e-supposed-to-have-really-easy-skill-checks) is Probably Incorrect based on the 'thanks' comment the OP placed on one of the answers.  I have added an inquiring comment.

1 in 26 is less than 1 in 20, so we're doing pretty good compared to some people.