# The [rules-as-written] tag is a good tag, but we've made it sick. Let's cure it

Tags: discussion, tags, policy, rules-as-written

[rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) has two purposes right now:

- "this question is about the rules as written"
- "answer must obey special rules"

The latter makes it a meta tag. Meta tags are never, in the long run, a good idea. But tags are for describing what questions are about, and [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) doesn't *need* to have that second purpose.

There's a simple solution then: kill the special rules attached to [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) with fire, to save it from being a meta tag.

Putting pressure on answer content to suit the question is what **votes** are for, and we were foolish to try to legislate what is supposed to be already taken care of by the core mechanic of the site.

---

Before it's brought up — no, [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) is not a counter-example that shows that [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) can have special rules and work.

The special rules for game-rec don't attempt to replace voting and "this is off-topic" delete votes. It has special rules because otherwise those questions are *banned*. RAW questions aren't banned without their special rules, they don't need them to be permitted here. That lack of corresponding situations is why [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) is not a valid model to look to for how to handle the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag.

---

[rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is a meta tag. We normally burn meta tags with fire, but we can save it, by reversing what we did to it that made it into a meta-tag monster. A few minutes ago I was writing a proposal to burninate it, and I found myself writing that we would need to find a replacement because it's valid to ask questions *about* RAW, and *aboutness* is my sacred yardstick for measuring the non-meta-ness of a tag. And I realised that [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is the very tag we would naturally want to replace *itself* with.

So [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) isn't a meta tag, but we've made it into one by turning it into a tag that dictates what answers should say. It's a good tag that doesn't deserve burninating; we have to save it from the inevitable death that comes to all meta tags.

**We should save it** because it's valuable to a huge community we serve.

**We should save it** because it legitimately describes many of our questions.

**We should save it** because people have shown that they want to use it and that's how our tag folksonomy is supposed to work.

**We should save it** because questions about RAW are on-topic and we need a tag for those.

**We should save it.**

It should not be a meta tag. We are undermining all its good work and value by making it a meta tag. We're grown-ups, we can handle people answering questions tagged [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) with answers that don't respect the tag. We can use our votes, including delete votes. We can use our words.

We don't need a site policy to make those answers go away. We really don't need a site policy that *doesn't even work* and wastes so much of our energy and time in divisive arguments about how to fix a problem we've inflicted on ourselves.

Vote with me to set [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) free from the special rules that are weighing it down. Let it do its job in tandem with the voting system. We're competent people here, we can handle telling people with votes and comments that they've made a mistake by ignoring the tag. And sometimes, we might find, that a question tagged [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) gets a really good answer that challenges the frame with a non-RAW solution. The way we expect the site to work.

We need [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written). We don't need policy on how it's used or how its answered.

---

*Current discussion context that's obvious now but will be harder to find as this meta ages:*

- [Experiential audit of [rules-as-written], please?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5189/experiential-audit-of-rules-as-written-please)
- [What, exactly, is the RAW tag for?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/what-exactly-is-the-raw-tag-for) (and every meta *it* links to)

Comment: One major concern I have with the RAW tag is that it can't be used solo on a question. generally when that's the case it's a marker of a problematic tag.

Comment: @waxeagle That's true... Wait! Maybe it isn't? I think a question about the community culture around RAW would stand on its own and be on-topic. Such a thing would be at the edges of our subject such that a badly written one would be off topic, but I don't think that means a well-written, on-topic question about the RAW phenomenon itself is impossible.

Comment: Just thought of a wild possibility: RAW-ness is *integral* to some questions. It's intimately tied to the game being played. And in some analyses, the *game* being played when RAW is required, vs when rulings are the order of the day, is almost a completely different game. And, RAW culture is quite game-specific. Imagine for a moment if we had [dnd-3.5e-raw] or [dnd-4e-strict]...

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've actually strongly considered writing such a Q&A (with [rules-as-written] as the only tag), since I think a lot of people *badly* misunderstand why RAW questions get asked in the first place, and what value those who are interested in them place on them.

Comment: @KRyan Exactly! A self-answer about RAW culture is totally a valid question here, and could in theory bear just [rules-as-written].

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Can I vote in you to President?

Comment: I think an exception for this one instance is actually valuable. Valid answers on this site are a bit different than other sites because a good answer could be one that completely ignores the rules of the system the question is about, which is unacceptable for most other sites and would be flaggable. I made a [comment](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/the-rules-as-written-tag-is-a-good-tag-but-weve-made-it-sick-lets-cure-it#comment13044_5212) as such on @KRyan's answer which helps explain the distinction.

Comment: Is a tag that can't be used alone justified, in cases where it saves you supporting a DND-RAW tag, a GURPS-RAW tag, a Storyteller-RAW tag (the mind boggles) etc? Even if "playing to the rules" is actually or almost useless in the absence of knowing what game you're playing, it'd be a common modifier to other tags because it corresponds to a common and recognisable playing style.

Comment: @SteveJessop In practice it's not a common modifier at all, as the RAW tag gets used almost exclusively with D&D. Check out the related tags in the tag's sidebar: only WOD (3% of questions) and DFRPG (1%) have every also gotten the tag, while 96% are D&D+PF's. Boggling is not a danger.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: well OK, I chose my examples badly, but it gets used with several different flavours of D&D including Pathfinder :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop What I'm unclear on is what kind of difficulty supporting a [*-raw] tag for each of those games would cause.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Just the non-obviousness of the tag, I suppose. Similarly it would be weird to have a whole bunch of [*-spells] tags on the basis that questions about spells (a) are usually about a particular game, not spells in general and (b) being about [spell]s in general but not [magic] in general is a pretty small niche for a question to hit. I suppose really I'm casting FUD on the "can it be used alone?" rule of thumb for tags, especially since "what game/version?" and "what aspect of play?" are somewhat orthogonal concerns.

Comment: .. tbh I thought "[*-raw]" was a straw man, I'm surprised you want me to rubbish it instead of you (and everyone) immediately feeling it's a rubbish idea ;-) In short, though, I strongly suspect but don't know for sure that such hierarchical tags would be hard to use, and impossible for non-regulars. So I wouldn't want [spells] or [raw] to be assessed on the "use alone" basis.

Comment: @SteveJessop I see what you mean. We do accept that [spells] is super-useful, and I don't immediately see how it could be used alone, so maybe it's a meta tag but that's okay... That's good food for thought.

Comment: I’m really displeased with the way that the RAW tag can act as a trap for newbies, [like here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53295/8012). That is not an awesome answer in any case, but it seriously bugs me that newbies need to read a tag wiki to avoid this land mine.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn’t **have** special rules.

A question defines a topic. Answers are required to stay on that topic (or stray only after addressing the question on-topic). RAW questions are no different in this regard.

The only reason that RAW is perceived to have special rules is because a lot of people want to *ignore the topic* of RAW questions, and post non-RAW answers, and then are upset when those answers get down-voted or deleted. They are upset and feel that it must be because the RAW tag is special. They want to encode this perceived specialness in the tag wiki, because they feel “burned” because they didn’t understand the question in the first place.

But the tag isn’t special. Posting “Well, I don’t know the rules, but this has worked really well for my games in the past,” which would otherwise be an acceptable answer, is off-topic for such a question, and should be downvoted and/or deleted *exactly* the same way as “Well, I don’t know anything about 5e, but in 4e we did this and it was awesome,” in a question tagged 5e should be. Posting “the rule says this,” when it does not, in fact, say that, should be downvoted just as “5e does this,” when they’re actually describing a 4e concept should be downvoted.

Comment: Except we do have special rules. [They're right here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/rules-as-written/info), where the first line in the tag's wiki says what *answers* must contain. No other tag wiki, excepting [game-rec] for its own *sui generis* reasons, has that; instead, they all say what questions the tag is for.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Like I said, that was added after people got upset by being “burned” by downvoted and/or deleted answers that were off-topic. If you want to remove that line, I suspect that’s fine, but I suspect we’ll start hearing about “getting burned” again.

Comment: Then it is a *de facto* special rule that, worse, is embedded in our community's culture. That sort of thing requires explicit overturning. That said, I agree with what this proposes we do. I just don't agree that that's the current status quo.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Aside from the change to the tag wiki, what change in *behavior* are you proposing?

Comment: I'm proposing that we stop treating it specially. (If you're not already, then good; that might be why you're not seeing a problem, because you just might not be part of the problem.) Specifically, aggressive mod-deletes of answers should probably be scaled back. Let the downvoting and non-mod delete votes do the job there.

Comment: I suspect we won't hear much about getting burned anymore once this is overturned, because we've all had this exciting adventure together and have learned a very special lesson. New people will complain, sure, but we're here to say, sorry, the votes disagree that this is useful on this question, and that's how the site's supposed to work.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I do fear that, just as there are a fair number of people who want to ignore the topic for their own answers, will also do so for their voting. That is part of the reason I have aggressively flagged non-answers as such. The majority here is not interested in RAW, which makes me worry about them voting by their own preferences rather than by how well an answer addresses the question actually asked (i.e. including the setting of the topic to the domain of the RAW).

Comment: I admit that's a possibility. But I'm not sure that there is any danger or harm caused by that possibility. If non-RAW answers are popular on RAW-wanting questions, the asker is still going to checkmark what's most useful to *them*. And it's worth recalling: votes are for what is useful to *others* who have read the question. It's not a popularity contest. Popular non-RAW answers are those likely to be well-written frame-challenges that help those who are in similar situations but accept non-RAW solutions. And a non-RAW answer being popular doesn't take votes away from faithfully-RAW answers.

Comment: That's how stuff works on every other tag, and it doesn't cause harm: egregiously-bad answers get downvoted, "hey that doesn't answer the overt question but wow does it solve the problem" seemingly-off-topic answers get voted up, and the asker doesn't always agree and accepts a less-popular answer that they like better.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have issues with it when an answer is **not clear** that it's not RAW, and thus can mislead users into thinking it is. And there are a number of answers like that on the site. (Actually, I have a big problem with this even if it’s *not* tagged RAW, if the answer gives the impression that it’s out of the book.) A high-voted, non-RAW answer to a RAW question gives the inaccurate impression that the answer is RAW. And per Challenging the Frame, those answers *should* be downvoted unless or until they address the question on-topic (i.e. by RAW) *first*.

Comment: (I have absolutely no problem with challenging the frame on RAW questions after the RAW answer's been offered; I do it myself often. RAW is frequently not actually a good way to rule things; you still have to answer the question first.)

Comment: Is a downvote and a comment asking for improved clarify insufficient? (Yes, "this isn't actually what the book says, -1!" will often get deleted, but that's because it's a bad way to comment. I mean "Can you cite this answer? I can't find anything in the book that says it works how this answer says it works" should be sufficient to both help the answer and warn readers, and is constructively-written enough to survive comment cleanups.)

Comment: (Requiring answers to provide a RAW answer before a non-RAW treatment is the kind of special rule I'm saying [rules-as-written] shouldn't have. Our challenging-the-frame meta is a help meta for writing better answers, not a deletion policy. When the answer is egregiously off topic it gets deleted because it's egregiously off topic, not because it fails our frame-challenge meta (non-)policy.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don’t think that is (or should be) a special rule, I think it very much **is** (or should be) required to answer the question, as asked, on topic, before you go providing some other answer to the question you think they should have asked. XY problems might be a real thing, but if the question is valid and answerable, it deserves an answer *first*. This kind of goes back to my general ... frustration with this line of meta discussion: there is a lot of very patronizing assumption that we know better than the people asking the question what they really want. We really don't.

Comment: That isn't even a general rule though. We have one official rule that governs whether an answer is deletable as off-topic, and it's contained in the "not an answer" flag: "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." Attempting to answer the underlying question, or providing a kind of solution that the asker says they don't want, is not part of any site rule or policy on answer content. Only: does it *attempt* to answer the question. Honest out-of-box answers are kosher.

Comment: We have, perhaps, become too accustomed to the way [game-rec] answers get deleted, which *is* done how you describe. That skewing of our standards is one of the sins I think [game-rec] is guilty of.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I **strongly** disagree that what you describe counts as "answering *the* question." It doesn't. It answers some other question that the answerer imagines is the "better" question, whatever that means. It's presumptuous, rude, unhelpful, against the rules, and should be dealt with as such.

Comment: *Please* read the not-an-answer flag text again. It is a *very* high bar. I understand you disagree... but I believe you're disagreeing with a feature of the site that is fundamental. Use your RAW skills to find me where our site's rules of use say what you're advocating for. Give it a literalist reading. The rule **is not** that it "answers the question" as you assert: the only rule is that it "attempts to answer the question". That makes out-of-bounds answers absolutely kosher by SE rules. Altering that is proposing special rules.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "I have no interest in what the rules say, here's what *I* say," is in no way, shape, or form even *attempting* to answer **the** question, if the question is "What do the rules say about this?"

Comment: That's a fairly extreme example that is not a useful for discussing the line between valid downvoting and valid not-an-answer flagging, which by-design do not overlap at all. Can you give an example that is actually a line-defining example instead of a far-from-the-line example? I would like to agree that that is a good not-an-answer flag example, but I can't because you've tied it to agreeing with your assertion that answers must provide a in-box answer first, and that's excluding the relevant middle I'm trying to discuss.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sure, [here's a recent one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51354/4563). The question was tagged RAW, and the answer literally starts with inaccurate statement about the status of “living” as a game-term, and then dives into explicitly-not-what-was-asked-for answer about what living means in real life.

Comment: Great, that's a good example. That? That does not qualify for the not-an-answer flag, because [SE design and policy is that not-an-answer flags are invalid when an answer is merely incorrect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122633/increase-in-inappropriate-not-an-answer-flags). Incorrectness is for downvoting. It being deleted due to the pressure of assertions that it isn't an answer is exactly the kind of losing-our-way problem I'm getting at. Our use of the site tools is getting sloppy and causing damage.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I strongly disagree that the flag was inappropriate. The question literally and explicitly said *they did not want an answer along those lines* and that was completely ignored. That's not merely incorrect, that is answering the question you want to answer rather than the question that was asked, and that has no business on this site.

Comment: To illustrate my point, I would still flag that answer even if they had been correct that “living” was not present in any of the game’s glossaries. Even if that were the case, the answer was of zero use in solving the problem presented in the question. The question was not whether or not one should rule humans as living at the table – that was never in dispute. The question was what, if anything, the rules had to say about it. And that answer did nothing to address that question.

Comment: "Zero use" is *defined* network-wide as only for downvoting. There is, by design, no overlap with the not-an-answer flag. Your use is explicitly invalid, as explained by the people who run the network. As someone who respects rules as written, I think you should stop and consider that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Just because they are not the same thing does not mean that one answer can't deserve both. The answer did not attempt to answer the question. It, in fact, attempted to answer the question that the question *made explicit pains to emphasize it was **not.***

Comment: Failing to include or successfully execute a challenge frame is not = to not attempting to answer the question. [The FAQ on how to use the NAA flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) sets the bar very high for appropriate use of the flag: nonsense, new questions, commenting, "thank you", bumping. Explicitly invalid uses of the flag include "The answer is wrong or inaccurate, or you disagree with it". Not answer the question *how* the asker wants it answerd is not what the flag is for. That's for downvotes. This is fundamental.

Comment: See also [the linked, closed-as-duplicate meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/is-it-appropriate-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-if-it-doesnt-address-the), that exactly covers what you're talking about: flagging a question because it seems to answer related but different question that you think the answering user just prefers to answer. That flag was declined, and this decline was affirmed as correct because it is still an attempt to answer *this* question. Albeit not how the asker would like. And then they're told that they're welcome to downvote instead.

Comment: This may be causing problems with your mental model of how to use SE. That sucks, I've been there, and it's a known phenomenon that it's extremely hard to adjust internal models when they're explicitly contradicted, or even see the contradiction for what it is. I can only say that it's worth allowing some time to pass to allow it breathing room.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's a terrible ruling, and all the more so because it's an FAQ entry hidden away on a separate site that contradicts the wording of the actual flag that people here see.

Comment: I would like to affirm that we do not delete answers as "not an answer" just because they are in some deviation from the poster's intent.  That's what voting is for. I delete answers that are totally and profoundly misguided, but one of our flag-decline reasons is "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" - there's a difference between "not an answer" (a comment or rant or discussion or question or confused irrelevance) vs. "an answer I don't like."

Comment: @KRyan That the evidence contradicts your interpretation of the wording should, if you're being honest with yourself, lead to re-evaluation of your interpretation, not rejecting the evidence. You cannot reject Meta.SE as authoritative anyway: it is the meta for the network's operation.

Comment: It's a bit ironic that all this discussion about RAW boils down to RPG.SE RAW...

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk Yes, a bit. Fortunately, it's a living community and not a book, so there's room for argument and living change, but unlike a book there is no room to accommodate different interpretations of the *current* rules. The analogy is less to a set of rules and more to a group's social contract + accepted rules: we can change our rules, but everyone necessarily plays by the same rules at a given moment, regardless of whether that's how they want, like, or interpret it to be, in order to participate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wasn't rejecting it, I was saying it's a bad choice on their part, and poorly communicated outward from there. I fundamentally disagree with their assertion that such answers are attempting to answer the question actually asked, as it was asked, which is what the flag description says.

Comment: @mxyzplk Neither factual accuracy nor personal dislike was really in question, so your comment is irrelevant. The question is whether or not it is valid to answer some other question you like better / imagine would be more helpful, rather than the one actually asked.

Comment: I understand your point.  It's just that we disagree.

Comment: @KRyan And so does SE: [here's that link again about flagging because you think it might be answering some other question they like better / imagine would be more helpful, rather than the one actually asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/is-it-appropriate-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-if-it-doesnt-address-the), where that use of the flag is unambiguously rejected as what the flag is for.

Comment: I would also suggest that y'all have maybe argued with each other enough for one day and should step away. Even for meta this is excessive and it's not just on meta.

Comment: Back on subject: that interpretation not being site-operation-as-usual, it does qualify as the kind of special rule I'm proposing be undone for the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is well within the site's purview to have a site-specific understanding of what that flag means, which is a point I intend to bring up in a meta thread in the future, because that ruling strikes me as patently absurd and extremely destructive with respect to the value of the site. That said, I agree that RAW shouldn’t have *special* requirements with respect to *actually answering the question asked*, that should just be a given from the word “go.”

Comment: @KRyan Cool, we can agree on that principle that there shouldn't be special rules for answers on certain tags (excepting game-rec as established, because banning). General rules, yeah, those can be hashed out elsewhere more appropriately. We can disagree again then. :)

Comment: @KRyan  The difference is bigger than the 4E/5E difference.  The answers should probably be treated the same way "D&D sux, play FATE instead" should be treated on Pathfinder rules clarification questions.

Comment: We pretty much need some mechanism that makes it clear that a person is seeking RAW-only answers. If I ask a question about C# or Christianity on a different network, I'll receive answers that conform to the rules of those systems. No one is going to suggest that I modify the compiler or alter the base tenants of a world-wide religion. Yet on RPG, it is very acceptable for an answer to completely make something up. So, *something* needs to exist to enforce the idea of "I want to stick to the rules of the system."

Comment: @Ellesedil That enforcement something is downvoting. We need nothing more.

Comment: I'm not convinced. If I answered a C# syntax question on StackOverflow with, "Just write your own compiler that handles it", I shouldn't be surprised when it gets flagged as not an answer *while* it's being downvoted into oblivion. But StackOverflow doesn't need any other descriptors on questions to state that answers should work with an existing compiler because that's already the law of the land there. A D&D 4e question here could attract answers that invent new rules, so the way answers work on RPG are already fundamentally different than other networks.

Comment: People are treating the tag as though it has special rules, [like here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53295/8012). That question does not mention RAW at all except from the tags, so a newbie who doesn’t read the tag wiki won’t know that house rules are challenging the frame.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I don't know what you want: that's not a special rule. Answers have to be on topic. The question doesn't explicitly mention 5e, either. Your comment in response to BESW is a misstatement of what the meta here has said. The tag wiki is *not* why that answer is not answering the question and why it constitutes challenging the frame.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Your comment on the question itself is *better* (certainly no harm in having requirements made explicit), but since my answer is very much “current practice is fine” and has precisely as many votes as doppelgreener’s “people need to state their requirements explicitly and not rely solely on the tag,” your claim that it is expected or required that those requirements be edited in “per [this] meta discussion” is simply untrue. That opinion has not reached any kind of consensus.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, that’s exactly why I made the comment, because that use of the tag is in dispute, as evidenced both by the lack of consensus in answers, *and* the large net positive on the discussion post itself.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That only means that the discussion is worth having, not that any particular course of action is espoused. Since my answer is literally to *not* change anything, you claim too much when you say that this meta discussion requires the person to explicitly state their RAW requirement.

Answer (score 6):

I'm all for healing it, but when we heal it, will there actually be a valuable tag left?

The [rules-as-written] tag evolved for classifying questions that:

- were asking about the rules, or how something would work inside the rules
- wanted answers to do some combination of: stick exclusively to the rules themselves, take the writing literally, make *nothing* up (no house rules or fiats), cite the rules, and so on.

At this point, the tag was fine, it was just describing the question.

However, at some point, a lot of people started using [rules-as-written] as a short-hand for their requirements, and *stopped writing* those requirements, which turned it into a meta-tag which implied rules on answers. To complicate the matter, we don't always agree on what those requirements *are*, and people stopped saying them explicitly.

So we have two options for dealing with this.

- Don't let [rules-as-written] become a *substitute* for explaining RAW requirements. Questions still need to explain those requirements clearly, leaving no need for [rules-as-written] to imply anything extra. *Then* the tag returns to just describing the content of the question, and categorising questions that do that.
- Make [rules-as-written] no longer be about the second bullet point. However, that will mean it's just for questions about the rules, which means it's the [rules] tag, which we don't need.

Comment: Hm. I'm not convinced on its face, but still, "Hm."

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did some rewriting to poke at the core of the issue.

Comment: How is this any different from *any* system tag? There are loads of questions, with any given system tag, that do not indicate the system *at all* except through the system tag. And that’s not a problem. This entire line of reasoning is predicated on the as-yet-undemonstrated assumption that users are making mistakes. There is no evidence that they actually are in any significant quantity that I have seen.

Comment: @KRyan This isn't about anyone making mistakes (I only mentioned that as an aside, and please note the emphasized *might.*). It's based on the idea tags shouldn't impose rules on answers, they're there to describe the question. I'm fine with system tags being in this weird situation; they're unambiguous shorthand for saying "I'm playing ..." before the same words in the question, and we get no gain out of making people repeat themselves doing that.

Comment: @doppelgreener And I consider the RAW tag equally unambiguous, and like I said, I haven’t seen any evidence that the hypothetical ambiguity is actually confusing anyone who applies the tag.

Comment: @doppelgreener But your own comment states that the *reason* the tag is insufficient on its own to describe the context and requirements of the question, as a system tag would, is because the system tag is “unambiguous shorthand,” from which it follows that you claim that using the RAW tag as similar shorthand is *ambiguous* and therefore bad, and I disagree with that. And, disagreeing with that, I see no reason to support requiring redundant statements in the text when the tag itself will do.

Comment: @doppelgreener I agree, and furthermore, since home brew rules are supposed to be Good Subjective (thus disallowing random stuff you just made up) I see very little need for the tag. We should just be stricter about home brew rules.

Comment: @KRyan Mmm. I'm thinking on this still. The RAW tag is in a weird spot for me, because it seems to get underused and I do think it has a degree of ambiguity (we agree on the general intent but not necessarily on the minutiae) -- and yet I think it is a valuable tag to have and a lot of people might not think to even say more than "I want RAW answers" and would find our asking them whether they need citations or not or so on to be silly. I think that despite its oddities I'm happy with it being the way it is, oddness and all. (But if we decide to change things, the above answer applies.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye The default state of a question on this site is neither RAW, nor inviting “homebrew.” Unless *that* changes and we define non-RAW as homebrew (won’t happen), the two tags aren’t opposites of one another, they’re separate things.

Comment: @KRyan See Brian's recent statement on meta, linked from my answer. Answers that *aren't* drawn from objective sources like RAW *must* obey Good Subjective and thus must be vetted by actual gameplay experience. Ad hoc rulings are Bad Subjective.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That is not at *all* the statement I get from that answer. I think your usage of either the term “homebrew” or “RAW” is different from mine... and I’m reasonably sure mine are the more common. Most people find a middle ground between RAW and homebrew, so to speak, where things are not strict-RAW but also not full on homebrew (which is very subjective but it’s still a common perception).

Comment: Regardless of what you call such rules, answers must either be objective or Good Subjective. If we actually follow that, what is the point of the RAW tag?

Comment: Quite simply, it is a collection of questions about the rules as written, and therefore answers should be responding within that context. That generally means it is more objective than most questions on this site, but it is not the same objective or good subjective.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this, I think two things need to happen:

1. Remove the special rules from the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag that make it a meta-tag.
2. Don't flag or down-vote answers that don't have citations if they aren't asked for.

While I absolutely agree that the special rules need to be burned, I think this also necessitates a change to our culture to reflect this. If we remove the rules from the tag, but continue to down-vote answers that don't have citations, even when citations aren't asked for, the problem will remain, only worse because now it's even less likely that a new user will know about this invisible rule.

To me, this goes back to the heart of Stack Exchange policy: **Questions must be held to a high standard of quality and clarity in order to maintain a healthy group of experts that provide good answers.** Right now, we're putting the onus on the answerer to know to add citations if the question being asked is about rules-as-written.

Instead, I say that we should put the onus on the questioner; they should be required to ask for citations if they think citations are needed. If someone asks a question that you think requires citations, but doesn't stipulate that, then you should edit that question to include this.

I would also say that **not all RAW questions necessarily need citations.** No other type of question *universally requires* this kind of rigor. As long as the answer is clear and useful without citations, then down-voting or flagging that answer is not helpful. If an answer could be improved by citations, then by all means edit them in. I expect that most good RAW answers will include citations anyways, but this should be considered an improvement to the answer, not a requirement for it to be considered valid.

Comment: I propose you edit this to remove your second bullet point. :) Because people can vote for whatever reasons they like, it's not something we have any grounds to make a policy about. People should be free to vote down if they think *this* answer should have citations, because that's how the system is design to organically identify answer quality. People are free to think that *every* answer to a RAW question should have citations, and vote down accordingly. Heck, people are free to think that every answer to a RAW question should include a picture of a chicken and vote down all that don't.

Comment: Shorter me: If you're going to advocate letting the system work as intended (and I **strongly agree** with that!), you ought not undermine it by proposing people shouldn't let the system work as intended. :)

Comment: And, to address an issue I see in the current wording: I think a change is necessary, yes, but I think it's necessary because we've lost our way and we need to change back to how we're supposed to use the site. Asking questions to be specific is just normal quality-control stuff; as is relaxing our uptightness about RAW-question answers lacking cites. These things are supposed to be judged case-by-case, in the context of a post's substance quality or lack thereof. I think this answer could emphasise that eliminating blanket requirements on Qs and As is a return to original best practices.

Comment: I don't see the citation thing as super-important, either way. The answer should be correct and should back up its correctness based on what the rules say, and it should source those rules, particularly in cases where different sources have different things to say. But sure, if the question-asker describes their understanding of the rules and the answer is just "yes, that's right" then whatever. Citing or not citing has not been a major issue in arguments over RAW answers.

Comment: @KRyan To the contrary, *requiring* citations as you say, is the bone of contention. If you don't see that as a special rule, that's exactly the problem I'm identifying: it is a special rule, and we need to recognise that and step back. Answers should be judged individually, by individuals. There is no room in the SE way for meta to dictate to individuals how to judge answers via a *habeus corpus* built up on meta.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I didn't mean to say that you can't down-vote for a lack of citations. I said that "RAW tag" + "No citations" does not *automatically* elicit a down-vote. As I mentioned, you can still down-vote if you think the answer is poor due to lack of a citation, but that should be because the answer is poor, not because it didn't follow the meta-rules of the RAW tag.

Comment: "The answer should be correct and should back up its correctness based on what the rules say, and it should source those rules", as far as I can tell, is saying that citations are required.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I didn't say a citation was required. I said that Back It Up! was required. Which, in context, has to be done by the rules, because any other source of backing it up would be irrelevant and off-topic. A citation clarifies dramatically which rule you are talking about, and generally any kind of complex or tricky question would be difficult to answer without it, but if an answer was well backed up and accurate, then it's a fine answer and should be upvoted.

Comment: Exactly my problem: Back It Up! is *not* required. BIU's scope is limited to subjective answers, and extending it to cover rules questions is not supported by the community's acceptance of the Back It Up! aka GS/BS principle.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, *I* am certainly going to downvote any answer that doesn't back up its claims. I don't think anyone should accept or upvote an answer to any question of the rules if the answer is simply asking you to take their word for it.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, and you're welcome to, because that's what the downvote button is for: individual judgements of utility. Even super-wacky reasons for downvoting have been aired and historically accepted, because that's explicitly how the site is supposed to work. Your *non-wacky* reason there, that others happen to disagree with, is even more acceptable than those wacky ones. But how you think *we* collectively should vote has by intentional design no power or relevance. That's the beauty of SE: it harnesses disagreement for the greater good, via clever voting mechanics. :)

Comment: @AgentPaper Any comment on the suggestion to drop the second bullet point?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No. The hidden rule of "you must have citations" for the RAW tag is the crux of the problem, so breaking the culture of requiring citations, even when the question doesn't ask for them, is crucial to the solution. Removing the rule from the tag itself is one thing, but if we don't also remove it from our culture, nothing will have changed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully better explain my position.

Comment: I understand that, but I think this states the "don't do that" the wrong way. In the context of agreeing with this by upvoting, that amounts to saying "yes, I agree that policy should be that nobody can downvote/flag just for lacking cites". Since that's fairly extreme *as policy*, few people are going to upvote it and many will downvote it. Which is a shame, because that doesn't appear to be what you intend this to say. But fair, because we don't want to solve the current special rules by just creating new ones.

Comment: Besides all that about wording though; as I said above, downvoting for lacking cites is a perfectly fine thing for people to do. Flagging for it is invalid, but voting is *precisely* for expressing how well or poorly an answer meets your *personal* criteria, no matter how good or weird those criteria are. Harnessing people's personal judgement (and averaging it out to hide the outliers) is the heart and soul of Stackexchange.

Answer (score -4):

We should not try to rehabilitate the tag. Instead, we should more aggressively [enforce Good Subjective for home brew and house rules](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5154/8012). If people are discouraged from posting arbitrary, ad hoc rules then there is much less need for the RAW tag for any reason. We are only supposed to post RAW, RAI, and fully vetted house rules in the first place.

Answers that focus on unvetted, ad hoc rules are Bad Subjective and should be treated as such. Regular users may downvote them or comment linking to the Good Subjective rules (either the general rules or Brian’s linked post). Simply following established SE policies here greatly reduces the need to demand RAW for rules clarification questions.

That narrows the scope for RAW questions to thought experiments and rants in disguise, the sorts of question where somebody points out an absurd or surprising implication of the rules as written, and asks if it’s really true. Such questions are popular but also a rough fit for SE.

Comment: This eliminates the ability of users to filter by, search for, favorite, or ignore the RAW tag and therefore questions using it. That would diminish the utility of the site for many.

Comment: @KRyan I don't agree that's a fact. On the contrary, it appears to be SE policy that meta tags like RAW are not only *not* critically useful, but instead something to be generally avoided. If you disagree, please support your claims in your own answer, because if you do have objective evidence for your position, it would be a useful answer.