# Discussion on thread "Artificer Eldritch Cannon Protector temp hit points and Wildshape"

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, policy, game-systems

Currently there is an edit war with regards to the [dnd-5e] tag on this question: [Artificer Eldritch Cannon Protector temp hit points and Wildshape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177548/artificer-eldritch-cannon-protector-temp-hit-points-and-wildshape)

The question is unambiguously about D&D 5e, but there doesn't seem to be agreement on how to handle it.

I would like to hear some opinions on what should be done on this particular question. I think eventually the OP will return to state the system, but it would be useful to discuss how to avoid future disagreements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the “Don’t Guess the System” policy?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11279/what-is-the-don-t-guess-the-system-policy)

Comment: The linked Q&A represents moderator, *not* user policy claiming a consensus that doesn't represent the user base at large. I voted to leave open -from review.

Comment: @Akixkisu That Q&A is the moderators summarizing the standing policy. I don't think changing the policy every time a slight change in votes is going to be sustainable, especially given that one side is going to be much more motivate to vote over time. For the '5e' specific one we handled an exception, but since this has now happened twice it may warrant a separate discussion.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I agree regarding sustainability but disagree with making it part of the faq when that faq claims a consensus where there is none. A faq with a disclaimer that accurately represents the ongoing and reoccurring issues of the policy would be honest to the community, even if moderators achieve it as politicians instead of police officers.

Comment: @Akixkisu I welcome you to make that suggestion to that Q. Its goal is to accurately represent the current status. And that policy is (at least to my mind) still in effect (see the moderator note on the re-revisit). There are clearly things here which needs to be discussed, but for now I say to treat the policy as standing.

Comment: Related: "[Does adding the system tag to this question violate the “never guess the system” policy?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9976)" and "[hould this question about “the Wildemount Chronugy subclass ability chronal shift” be tagged as D&D 5e without OP specifying it?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10085)" and [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10145) to the question "Does the community agree with the part of the “never guess” policy regarding asking meta first?"

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thank you for the link, I am aware of the various policies that may be useful in this case. I am asking about this specific case and how we should handle specific cases in the future. Thanks for your assistance and understanding.

Answer (score 7):

## We should do nothing until the question is clarified.

Two instances of edits by different users accompanied by two rollbacks of the same user don't make an edit war. By majority vote, our current [policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9805/44723) is to apply a principle of best judgement. However, it is a narrow vote that has been swinging in both directions on different occasions (it initially had extremely favoured support in case of overturning the old policy, then later it had substantial support in keeping old policy, and currently it has narrow support (one vote) in favour of overturning old policy.

Engaging further takes energy that we can spend at a different place.

Comment: there are enough contextual clues to tag it 5e and reopen; I see no reason to leave it closed but I am also not interested in the aggrivation, and, the related that @user-024673 Q&A covers most/much of what the question is concerned about; I am not sure that the Q in question isn't a dupe of that one.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Notably, people have and *will* argue that even when we are sure of the system by context clues [we *still* shouldn't add in the tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10090)

Comment: @Medix2 And that would be wrong; I am getting really tired of the word "policy" on this stack.