# Can we reapply the Pathfinder 2e tag to this Pathfinder 2e question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, pathfinder

[Razzle-Dazzle and success vs Blindness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185716/razzle-dazzle-and-success-vs-blindness) is asking about two Pathfinder 2e features, linking to the Pathfinder 2e reference document for both features (`2e.aonprd.com`; the system is also highlighted at the top of the page). I added the [pathfinder-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-2e) tag since it was contextually clear what game the question was asking about, and then edit was rolled back. There are currently four close votes on this question with a comment requesting information about the system.

Can we apply the [pathfinder-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-2e) tag to this question and keep it open / reopen it if it's closed?

Comment: Related questions: "[When is it OK to assume the system without it being considered a guess?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9566)" and "[What qualifies as guessing on a system?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8849)"

Comment: @Medix2 OP of that question linked to the 2nd edition version of the feat on the official archive.

Answer (score 16):

#### The system is utterly clear *and* we should add it

András has [been asking PF2e questions lately](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/9552/andr%c3%a1s?tab=questions&sort=newest), and this question even links to material from that system. This is extremely similar to [questions linking to D&D Beyond](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9988). The system is *undeniably* clear and András *clearly* knows how the site works and just forgot to add the tag (I have done this myself as well in the past).

Comment: Why did you edit it out then? Was there any specific reason?

Comment: @Baskakov It is simply [policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11279) to do so: "The question asker must explicitly state the game system (and edition, for games with multiple editions) that they’re asking about."

Comment: I _did_ forget, corrected now

Comment: [One of the most recent discussions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11287/30214) of it seems to have "let experts be experts" as the highest-upvoted answer. See [this Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9806/30214) too.

Comment: @Baskakov Your first question is explicitly and **exclusively** about the phrase 5e and absolutely *nothing* else. It is a very specific exception to the general policy, which is described, in its entirety, in the link i provided earlier. The second link you've provided is evidence only of how votes haves changed over time. The original question states:

Comment: "After 3 months, the community's highest voted answer is sitting at +54/-22 and advocates for not changing the policy according to the moderators' proposal, which ranks below it in score at +47/-22. As the community failed to achieve a consensus to change the status quo, we will continue to enforce the policy as we have in the past. Separate refinements made notwithstanding." This has not changed, and no number of votes made after that moment will change this. The vote order may have changed, but the policy decidedly has not.

Comment: So you know the policy, disagree with it, and were making a point by following it when it was clearly wrong?

Comment: @András We *have* to follow it. It is, quite literally, **policy**

Comment: I mean ... nobody forces us to make these edits. We do not, in fact, have to do them if they are not consistent with what we believe is best for the site. While I work to make sure the affirmative actions I do take help the site work better, nobody's forcing me to do them and I can choose not to take action. (In other words, I do not _have_ to roll back an edit if I don't want to.) Meanwhile, I can take community sentiment on board as guidance for the actions I do take. I took the linked post of "let experts be experts" as guidance for me to add the tag that was obviously indicated.

Comment: @Medix2 - but see [When is it OK to assume the system without it being considered a guess?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9566/20770)

Comment: @Medix2, you do not even _have to_ follow the law. There might be consequences, but you can always decide that you rather take those.

Comment: @Vynce I'm sorry, but you are wrong: "[What is the “Don’t Guess the System” policy?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11279)" details the policy in full. What you've linked was a specific question which had no generalizability. See the following: "[Re-revisiting the "don't guess the system" policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9805)" and note that the vote totals there **do not matter**. The question states, plainly:

Comment: @Vynce "After 3 months, the community's highest voted answer is sitting at +54/-22 and advocates for not changing the policy according to the moderators' proposal, which ranks below it in score at +47/-22. As the community failed to achieve a consensus to change the status quo, we will continue to enforce the policy as we have in the past. Separate refinements made notwithstanding." Recent votes changing this fact have not changed and will not change what is actually currently policy. An entirely new Meta would need to be asked

Comment: That said, as @András mentioned, we are free to break the law and face whatever in the world the consequences are. I have been, for a long time, very afraid of doing so because I felt like it incentivized or would lead to totally anarchy and edit wars. I am now less sure of this and could see active refusal to obey the policy as being a statement of sorts or at least as not being inherently bad. You are free to do what you want and face the consequences of your actions, but the policy is fully detailed in the question I linked above: "The question asker must explicitly state the game system"

Comment: @Medix2, I see the value in teaching the newcommers, but it is enough to look at the reputation to know if it is a newcommer, or someone was forgetful. In the latter case I see no value in _not_ guessing the system when the indicators are strong.

Comment: @András As I have said already twice in these comments: it is policy to do so. I don't follow the policy because I see value in teaching newcomers, I follow the policy because it is policy. That policy applies the same way to everybody whether a new member with 1 reputation or a long time member with 100k reputation. It doesn't matter whether I agree with the policy or not, the actions that it states must be taken are clear: questions that do not have their system explicitly stated by the asker will be closed. We *can* ignore the policy, but following the policy means your question gets closed

Comment: It's not about seeing value, it's about following the policy, which makes no exception for seasoned users. If there is still some part of my numerous comments here that you do not understand, I would be happy to explain it. I'll try a summary though: The policy is clear and applies to everyone. That doesn't mean you have to follow it.

Comment: @Medix2 First, the "don't guess the system policy" explainer meta does not define the policy in full. For example, it does not even cover the very real practice of making case-by-case metas to examine things, which even the answer in favor of keeping the policy brought up. Secondly: of course our votes matter! They always matter. Why the heck would they not matter? Who else is making and deciding the policy here if not us? That's the community's entire job. Don't tell us our votes don't matter, please, or you're even disenfranchising your own decision-making power. Your votes matter.

Comment: @doppel As you definitely know, people have talked, at length, about the problems that would arise if the policy changed every time the vote totals changed. We also have precedent (twice) that changes in vote totals do not change policy. The vote totals matter in the sense that they show *something*, but they don't change the policy.

Comment: But I am also, as I am sure you know too, fed up. I am *constantly* being told that I am wrong, incorrect, or misguided on this topic by people on each and every side and I am sick and tired of it. I will likely stop any and all discussion of it at this rate because it is actively causing me harm

Comment: I have not been part of many of those discussions, and I sure have not gone and said anything along the lines of "yes, it would be a problem to reflect vote totals in our policy, so a significant shift in how people are voting cannot change policy". If we changed it every time a single answer was one vote ahead while they were neck-and-neck, that would not be sound decision-making, but a large gulf and established trend is exactly what had us decide to keep the policy last time & it's also a fair basis on which to say the community's will has changed, and how we operate should reflect that.

Comment: Ok, discussion here seems to have shifted over to a unresolved topic, and due to the nature of comments and short references to facets and issues it's generating a lot of misunderstanding. How to handle the seen change in votes has so far been arbitrated by the mods, and we'll apologize for the [fuller discussion on that](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11595/52137) being late. I'll suggest moving any further effort there.