# Should we have a Monsters of the Multiverse tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e

The recent release of the D&D 5e *Monsters of the Multiverse* has changed the stat blocks of [around 200 creatures](https://www.themonstersknow.com/monsters-of-the-multiverse/), and for PCs eliminated the concept of subraces, revised many racial traits, and changed the way racial ability points work at character creation.

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/199484/23547) asks about a bugbear racial trait specifically found in *Monsters of the Multiverse* and would not apply to someone running a bugbear PC according to the legacy rules in *Volo's*.

Should there be a [monsters-of-the-multiverse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters-of-the-multiverse) tag to apply to such questions moving forward?

Answer (score 4):

### I don't see this as necessary

We generally don't have tags for source books.<sup>1</sup> If a question is about X thing from book Y, it is really only *about* X and should be tagged as such. If and when specifying the source is relevant, that should must be done in text and not relegated to tags (they simply aren't supposed to do that duty).

I'm basing this partially on an expectation that most will simply be playing with the newer version, though in any case distinguishing version or source is the job of the question body.

Of course, it's possible this will change in the future and we should revisit it then, though for now let's not add a tag which will only bloat a handful of questions (and the tag slots on these questions seem already quite cramped).

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm sure you'll find some examples, but to my understanding those are books which create subdomains of the system on their own, not merely republish material with updates.

Comment: Does it matter that this is not just a sourcebook with _optional_ rules, but one which is stated to _officially revise_ existing rules, and as such is a new 5e standard?

Comment: @Kirt Arguably the opposite. Since it's not optional there's a fair argument that it's just core and thus *not an optional subdomain*. We do have tags for a number of settings (which are basically a kind of optional subdomain) but even then we don't tag for source just because the question is from a given setting. I think I'd rather see a tag for "legacy content" or some-such, as that is the optional subdomain. But I'm not sure I really like that either

Comment: @Someone_Evil In [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11852/62294) I discuss how the [theros] and [ravnica] tags are used for questions about the game mechanics unique to the setting rather than material published in the book that is mostly setting agnostic.

Comment: "*If a question is about X thing from book Y, it is really only about X and should be tagged as such.*" Not too long ago [I was told this isn't the case](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12121/is-the-quintessence-tag-quintessential). Seems like the policy related to tagging isn't exactly clear.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, well, I'm here presuming X is a thing for which we have tags. My point is that we don't tag for source (unless that *actually* is a collectable topic, but I don't see the latest revision in core to be so)