# The [rules-as-written] tag - still useful or is it junk?

Tags: discussion, rules-as-written

A brief history of the [rules-as-written] tag (though all the discussion is ~2 years old):

- [What, exactly, is the RAW tag for?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/what-exactly-is-the-raw-tag-for) (A good summary of what the tag's for and other meta Q's related to it)
- [The [rules-as-written] tag is a good tag, but we've made it sick. Let's cure it](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/the-rules-as-written-tag-is-a-good-tag-but-weve-made-it-sick-lets-cure-it) (newer, but I don't understand what it's saying)
- [The [rules] tag has just been burninated (again), let's blacklist it](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4932/the-rules-tag-has-just-been-burninated-again-lets-blacklist-it) (a "rules" tag is not useful and is blacklisted)
- [Are our implicit-information tagging practices becoming a problem?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/are-our-implicit-information-tagging-practices-becoming-a-problem/5151#5151) (somewhat related, though that Q's about several things)

I have noticed the [rules-as-written] tag is becoming extremely common on the site.  We are [up to 570 uses of it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written), are getting more than 1 new one a day on average, and it appears to me most of them are using it as a pure synonym of [rules] as in "I'm asking a question about some rules" - which is not useful per the third link above.  Of course you're asking about the rules; most questions not about gm-techniques or problem-somethings are. Of course questions about the rules should be answered with rules citations or at worst table-tested rulings that meet [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) criteria. Answers that just say "well this is what I might do" should be downvoted and potentially deleted as bad answers, whether there's a rules-as-written tag on the question or not.

The tag is adding nothing to the vast majority of these questions. It's really only useful for fringe questions that intend to say "look I know that this is a pedantic loophole but come on and work the logic puzzle with me won't you"? (e.g. commoner cannons). I'm not sure that's tag-worthy; having any tag starting with "rules" becomes a default thing someone thinks they should add to a question because it's a rules question.

Here's the recent ones.

1. [Clarification of Blink Mechanics, or "Should Someone have Punched in my Sandwich?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/clarification-of-blink-mechanics-or-should-someone-have-punched-in-my-sandwich) - "How does this spell work, there was disagreement at my table?"  Slam dunk rules quote answer. No real "RAW" lawyering required.
2. [Can one enter Leomund's Tiny Hut from below?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73879/can-one-enter-leomunds-tiny-hut-from-below) - "How does this spell work, there was disagreement at my table?" As the spell doesn't say, all the answers are supposition and arguing from other perspectives anyway.
3. [Can monsters be summoned to appear in mid-air to drop onto enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73942/can-monsters-be-summoned-to-appear-in-mid-air-to-drop-onto-enemies) - "My PCs are trying an exploit is there a rule that says they can't?" Slam dunk rules quote answer.  No real "RAW" lawyering required.
4. [Hostage Situation: Do you miss, hit the hostage, or chance of either one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73761/hostage-situation-do-you-miss-hit-the-hostage-or-chance-of-either-one) - "We aren't sure if there's a rule."  Sadly the answers tend to jibber jabber about related things but a clear answer to the stated question is hard to find in there. Several of the answers are definitely not pure RAW.
5. [Can I use Relentless Endurance after failing the Relentless Rage Constitution saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/can-i-use-relentless-endurance-after-failing-the-relentless-rage-constitution-sa) - Slam dunk rules quote answer.  No real "RAW" lawyering required.
6. [Can you take a Squire at 3rd level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73602/can-you-take-a-squire-at-3rd-level) - two rules conflict, which way to rule?  Almost not RAW by definition, as the RAW is trivially in conflict.

And so on.  I don't see what value [rules-as-written] is adding to these questions - zero from a searchability and SEO point of view clearly (it doesn't appear in the search keywords analytics mods have access to, though those are limited), and I don't see any in terms of scoping the question or answers as it's being used.  50% of the RAW-tagged questions above have non-RAW answers and the OP seems fine with it.

If you look at a similar roundup of "just plain rules questions" they seem to be being answered identically.  Simple (or even not so simple) rules questions get rules quotes, where there's no clear RAW they get designer tweets, (hopefully tested) table interpretations, etc.  I contend if you took the questions tagged RAW off our front page, plus all the rules questions not tagged raw, took off the tags and mixed them up you would not be able to discern any difference.

If we're just tacking it on and the community's not e.g. enforcing no answers that aren't pure RAW on those questions (and there's no indication on any of them the OP objects to the non-pure-RAW answers), I contend the tag has effectively become [rules] and is superfluous and should be burninated and blacklisted.

Your thoughts are welcome.

Comment: This seems like a case where we have a bunch of newer folks who haven't gotten the memo re: how this tag is to be used yet...

Comment: Re: #2, isn't "The rules don't say you can't, and this other rule says you can except when specified otherwise" half the argument of most rules-lawyering?

Comment: @KRyan Put that in an answer as a positive value for the tag, where challenges to questions' assumptions are more productive. Don't invite mxyzplk to fight about it in the comments.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I figured it would just be an update to the question, but OK. (It was also an attempt to assume good faith and seek honest clarification.)

Comment: @KRyan Honest attempts of such can easily go wrong in delivery when it's a heated topic. :) It doesn't read that way; and besides, there's no real value to clarification if you already know it's wrong.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I *don’t* know that, because I don’t know exactly what was meant by that statement. I think such a clarification would also improve the discussion. But I’ll defer to you on this, since my judgment on what the best way to communicate on this subject is suspect.

Comment: I have to say, the "pedantic" bit is probably not helping the reception of this post. It jumps out at me every time I read it, and I have zero personal attachment to playing RAW or having a tag for it. Because yes,  it is a heated topic, and that's pretty darn dismissive. There are plenty of other ways to express the same concept, especially as a mod representing the site, and especially when you're trying to have a dialog with people you're effectively calling pedants.

Comment: I am not casting aspersions on the RAW play style.  My meaning us that normal rules questions are answered with rules anyway, serving RAW fine.  The only case in which the separate tag seems to make a difference is on questions where it is, consciously, a thought exercise on the edge of even RAW (commoner cannons, et al).  Rules questions with and without the tag seem to be answered in identical ways on this site.

Comment: On a personal level, I don't think we should support the kind of pedantic bickering that RAW requires anyways.  If that is a "playstyle", those **tables** should be burninated, the tag with it.

Comment: @Tritium21 Sorry, no. [That sentiment is unwelcome here, not the playstyle.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/can-we-affirm-that-rpg-se-embraces-a-plurality-of-playstyles) That comment is undeleted only because it is topical to unambiguously deny it.

Comment: Aaand that is why the use of "pedantic" here is a problem. I see the point you're trying to make, @mxyzplk, but it's still insulting and also easily extended to, well, any situation in which the rules must be puzzled out in a literal way. It's your assertion that normal rules questions get answered exactly the same, but others' assertion that RAW questions need to be made distinct. I'm not currently arguing either way on that, only that what's written here can rather easily look like a jab against the latter.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Supporting all playstyles is not something we should try and do.  RAW playstyle is UNWELCOME here.

Comment: @Tritium21 What? No it isn't. You might not wish to welcome it, but it's accepted policy to embrace all playstyles equally. You might want to weigh in on the meta involved if you feel that strongly, but there's a lot of weight of community and mod opinion to swim against: [Can we affirm that RPG.SE embraces a plurality of playstyles?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5174) I can unequivocally say that I can't stand the playstyle personally, but I have and will defend its representation here without hesitation or prejudice, and even work to support it. It belongs here as much as any.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie But it is an impossible task to support!  If humans could do rules-as-written there would be no judges in the legal.... This needs to be a new answer.

Comment: @Tritium21 “It is foolish to tell a man successfully doing a thing that it is impossible to do.” The playstyle and community exist. Not being able to comprehend its practical daily existence is not a fault that disproves its existence, it merely demonstrates that one doesn't understand that of which one speaks…

Comment: And on that note, no more “the RAW playstyle should be unwelcome/doesn't make sense/shouldn't exist” will be entertained in these comments, thank you. That's quite enough of that attitude—which *is* unwelcome here. Overturn the relevant meta policy first, or abide by it.

Comment: "Pedantic" is part of our site's definition of RAW.  See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/what-exactly-is-the-raw-tag-for, linked prominently in my question.

Comment: That may be so, but like it or not, "pedantic" carries an insulting connotation and is unnecessarily polarizing for a topic that is already super polarized. I am telling you this because I assume you're not trying to insult anyone, but it _feels_ like an insult regardless, thus it's probably not helping communicate your message. It's also pretty easy to run with for people who do want to insult -- see conversation above. (This is not the place to discuss redefining RAW in depth, but FWIW, I don't think it really belongs in our definition, either.)

Comment: I hear your concern but consider the context clear.

Comment: Having read a pile of comments again, I go back to a coment of yours from a bit over a year ago.  _I think the current usage of the RAW tag is not sufficiently a problem to merit this amount of debate, let alone impose some other onerous solution. "some people use a tag wrong, sometimes!" C'est la vie. – mxyzplk♦ Dec 3 '14 at 23:12_   Since then, 5e has grown, as has new user volume here at RPG.SE.  Right?  Tags -- not just here, but on the internet in general.  Not everyone is as "up" on them as experienced users on this site.  Learning curve issue, perhaps.

Comment: It wasn't a problem, at that time. It has become one, however, and it clearly goes beyond "learning curve" as we have community dissent on how the tag should be used and applied. Learning curve assumes a clear end state once you get past the learning. It is indeed similar in that there's way too much frenzy over what should be a pretty simple clarification of a tag and wiki, but since we are in a situation where no one wants to agree on what the definition of "is" is, it appears there's no resolution without way, way too much nonsense in this case too.

Answer (score 20):

**Burning the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag is extreme and would be damaging to the site; other, less drastic methods should be found to alleviate any problem behaviour arising from its over-broad use.**

Eliminating the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag would censor RAW questions *de facto*, though not *de jure*. The tag focuses the attention of appropriate experts who would otherwise have to sift through many questions they're wholly uninterested in. Getting rid of it would alienate experts from a large and popular category of question, reducing the quality of the site's answers on this topic.

Unfortunately, using [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) in place of [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) also creates noise obscuring RAW questions from RAW experts. If this is really a common practice, it should be dealt with--but removing the tag entirely makes the actual problem (failing to attract experts in the RAW lens) *worse*, not better.

(I suspect that re-naming the tag would obfuscate the questions from experts almost as much, and should be considered a desperate measure.)

I don't have an answer to how this should accomplished, but that's not what the meta question's asking: it's asking if [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) has outlived its usefulness and should be burned. I say, "[rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is still very useful and should not be burnt."

Comment: This I wholly agree with. If the tag is frequently being misused, a drastic measure like a rename may be appropriate. But a rename *is* a drastic measure, and should be avoided unless we have really compelling evidence that something needs to be done. (Like BESW, I cannot think of any less-drastic options.)

Comment: @KRyan Would a banner on RAW-tagged questions like the one that used to accompany game recommendation questions that explains the tag's meaning be an option? Personally, I think that's weird and also extreme, but that *is* less extreme than renaming or even torching the tag.

Comment: @HeyICanChan For right now, I feel like it’s premature to weigh different options, but if there actually is a problem, that could be a decent solution. The problem with it, to my mind, is that it implies the tag is “special” when it’s really not. But if there’s a problem, that could be a less drastic approach to solving it.

Comment: Even if the tag is being misused, and even if renaming could fix that, it would only make sense to do so if the cost of renaming it is less than the benefit of slightly cleaner tags. Also, note that he cost is fairly high on the clarity scale—"RAW" is the common and correct term for this thing, changing it will mean that this site has developed its own peculiar jargon.

Comment: @fectin Oddly though, changing it to [raw] has been opposed on the grounds that it's *not* the common or correct term.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't have a strong opinion on whether the phrase or acronym is more correct. I'd guess the phrase would be easier to find, which I think is the point, but either would be better than making up a peculiar term.

Answer (score 14):

## About other uses of tagging

Beyond the inherent scoping and, well, tagging value of the tag, I am also confused by this claim:

> zero [value] from a searchability and SEO point of view clearly

This is not clear to me. I don’t explicitly *search* for `[rules-as-written]` that often (though it has happened), but I have the tag favorited so that (if things were working correctly) such questions are called to my attention (and I want this feature back, which is why I have attempted to push that bug report as much as I can). If I did not spend as much time on this site as I do, such a search would be more likely.

As for SEO, “rules as written” *is* a term used in the broader RPG-playing community, at least within D&D. It is not implausible that it could be included in Google searches, though I have no independent knowledge that it actually is.

Answer (score 13):

## I would like to see evidence that the tag is misused.

As far as I can tell, the entirety of the alleged problem with the tag is the idea that it is used by people who don’t know what it means and don’t intend it. Yet in every single one of these discussions, we only get vague comments alluding to this problem, without any evidence. The last time we really dug down to look, someone came up with a list that they claimed were cases of misuse, and yet the majority of those questions that had accepted answers, had accepted the answer that followed the rules as written. Even, in some cases, above higher-rated answers that did not. Which is rather weak evidence.

The new list, in mxyzplk’s question, are all rules questions. As has been stated time and time again, rules questions do not require the RAW tag. **However,** questions with the RAW tag are pretty much always going to be rules questions. It is applied to rules questions to constrain what is being asked about: the text in the books themselves. **Just because it’s a rules question does not make the RAW tag superfluous.**

> I don't see what value [rules-as-written] is adding to these questions [...] I don't see any in terms of scoping the question or answers as it's being used.

Every single one of those questions is asking about the rules text, and every one of the answers to it cites rules text. The tag indicates that this is **not** a question of what should be done, or what would you have done, but what the rules actually say. That is how they have been answered. How is this a problem, again?

And, most importantly, **what evidence is there that this was not the intent of the author when the question was asked and tagged?**

As for the list that mxyzplk offers:

> 1. [Clarification of Blink Mechanics, or "Should Someone have Punched in my Sandwich?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/clarification-of-blink-mechanics-or-should-someone-have-punched-in-my-sandwich) - "How does this spell work, there was disagreement at my table?"  Slam dunk rules quote answer. No real "RAW" lawyering required.

So? The querent did not know the answer when they asked the question (that’s why they asked), so they did not know if would be a “slam dunk rules answer.” It is not necessary to “lawyer” in every rules-as-written answer, only in those where, ya know, it’s necessary. If this question had turned out to have a torturous interaction of rules, then it would have been – and an answer that didn’t, and just went with what they considered sensible without reference to the rules, would be a bad one where otherwise it would be a fine one by the default assumptions of the site.

> 2. [Can one enter Leomund's Tiny Hut from below?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73879/can-one-enter-leomunds-tiny-hut-from-below) - "How does this spell work, there was disagreement at my table?" As the spell doesn't say, all the answers are supposition and arguing from other perspectives anyway.

Here we have a problem with voting practices (many upvotes on a question that explicitly eschewed the rules as written; I for one have downvoted it), but since there is not yet an accepted answer to the question, we have no evidence that this answer is something that the querent wanted or will accept. The other answers do a better job of trying to work with only what is made available by the rules.

Moreover, challenging the frame is still an option on rules-as-written questions. As noted in that meta, doing so is a risk (I would not have downvoted the answer on a question not tagged rules-as-written), but risks do sometimes pay off. I don’t think it should here, but that’s neither here nor there.

If the OP does accept this answer, then he or she has accepted a non-RAW answer, which definitely suggests that the rules-as-written tag was applied erroneously. It does not, however, make that conclusion absolutely certain: it could have originally been intended, and then the querent was convinced by the frame-challenge. Also possible. But I would support the removal of the rules-as-written tag from the question in that case.

> 3. [Can monsters be summoned to appear in mid-air to drop onto enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73942/can-monsters-be-summoned-to-appear-in-mid-air-to-drop-onto-enemies) - "My PCs are trying an exploit is there a rule that says they can't?" Slam dunk rules quote answer.  No real "RAW" lawyering required.

As with #1.

> 4. [Hostage Situation: Do you miss, hit the hostage, or chance of either one?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73761/hostage-situation-do-you-miss-hit-the-hostage-or-chance-of-either-one) - "We aren't sure if there's a rule."  Sadly the answers tend to jibber jabber about related things but a clear answer to the stated question is hard to find in there. Several of the answers are definitely not pure RAW.

The accepted answer goes through all of the available rules, and only at the end notes that a gap in the rules and suggests a houserule. That is a reasonable frame-challenge in a rules-as-written answer. (On a sidenote, I think that the claim that there is no rule for that is not actually true, and intend to research that topic and either suggest an edit to that answer or offer my own.)

> 5. [Can I use Relentless Endurance after failing the Relentless Rage Constitution saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73689/can-i-use-relentless-endurance-after-failing-the-relentless-rage-constitution-sa) - Slam dunk rules quote answer.  No real "RAW" lawyering required.

As with #1.

> 6. [Can you take a Squire at 3rd level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73602/can-you-take-a-squire-at-3rd-level) - two rules conflict, which way to rule?  Almost not RAW by definition, as the RAW is trivially in conflict.

As with #1.

Comment: Of course they are rules questions and rules are cited in their answer.  Success.  So what value is the tag bringing?  We don't use them for vanity purposes, what is it adding?  There are many answers to just that last week of questions that have rulings, house rules, etc. suggested and there's no community blowback on them, which indicates it's not really serving a "RAW only here" signpost purpose effectively.  Loving RAW is fine, but the tag the way it's being used isn't adding value.

Comment: If the meaning of the [rules-as-written] tag is to categorise questions about “what the rules actually say”, it's just a synonym of [rules] and we-the-mods can summarily burn it under the existing consensus that a [rules] tag and its synonyms are inherently bad for the site. I don't think you intended to claim that, but that's what this answer appears to be claiming. Can you clarify what distinction you do see the tag has that makes it not just a [rules] synonym?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie On a [rules-as-written]-tagged question, voting should shun the house rules epiphany some dude had over his cornflakes and posted as an answer and favor an answer that's a strict, careful reading of the text by someone with experience with the problem. Without the querent narrowing intent, both are given equal weight. That's not to say the former's bad and the latter's good, but the former's not what the querent wants and the latter is--and that's indicated by the [rules-as-written] tag. Sure, the querent could just say that in the question, but then why have tags at all?

Comment: @HeyICanChan How do we reconcile that reading with the large number of RAW-tagged questions with intent-focused answers that get accepted by the querent?

Comment: @BESW That phenomenon is what this answer is asking for examples of.

Comment: @BESW the answer there is to make it more clear to users and question askers what the tag is meant to be for, rather than removing a valuable tool for discussion from the site.

Comment: @Forrestfire Just as it's reasonable to ask for evidence that the tag is being misused, I think it's also reasonable to ask for evidence that the tag is valuable when used properly: not every quality of a question needs to be tagged, so why is this quality so (apparently) obviously worth of tagging?

Comment: @BESW A game's rules form, well, the game; if a question is about the game's rules (the rules as written, that is), houserules and personal interpretations that conflict with the rules are not and should *never* be considered valid unless it has been established that the question asker is looking for those sorts of answers.

The RAW of a game is the only common basis for discussing a game. While it may not be particularly *relevant* in some games (like Fate), in other games (like  D&D 3.5), knowing the RAW is the most important factor in being able to understand the game.

Comment: I've just caught up on reading a few years' [tag:RAW] meta discussions and, while my head's thoroughly spun-round on the underlying issue, I really appreciate the defense you make of the anonymous *user* of the tag. No matter what happens to the tag I feel like it's better that we have a *de facto* ombudsman than not.

Comment: @BESW If there is a better way to be able to say "I am asking about the game itself, not your personal version of it. If you offer houserules instead of rules, your answer is not valid" than a tag that outright says that's what the asker is looking for, then I would support the implementation of that. I don't think there is one, though.

A good answer to a question with nonfunctional RAW could have both the RAW (aka the answer that matters) and possibly *suggestions* on how to handle it, but should *never* have only the latter.

Comment: Perhaps amending the tag to say "rules-as-written *only"* would help it be properly used more.

Comment: @BESW It sounds like you want the [rules-as-written] as the default and [house-rules] be exceptional, which *I* am totally good with but the *hobby as a whole* isn't. This isn't *Magic: The Gathering* where folks play for money *and* for fun but *all* fun which means opinions on that fun run rampant because nothing's at stake but a good or better time. That some folks--a (vocal?) minority--have their good time by being more legalistic than others is, I thought, why the tag exists: so it cuts out unwanted [Make it up yourself](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5940/8610) answers and the like.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Um. I have no idea where you got that impression. Have you read my meta post here, where I call for in-question specification of RAW? That kinda says I don't think it should be considered a default.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I see the problem - you are under the misapprehension that "a house rules epiphany someone had over their cornflakes" is *ever* an appropriate answer on this site.  It's not.  Only answers that are Good Subjective, Bad Subjective are, which Back It Up!.  This means all rules-y questions are best answered with a) raw if it exists, b) tested rulings/house-rules if not.  In fact, that tends to be the formula questioners even state when using the rules-as-written tag ("Well raw if it's there, or if not then...).  That's what all answers should be like, thus we don't need a tag for it.

Comment: @forrest We're not going to start assuming every question about a game's functioning that isn't about house rules or homebrew is about the view from the rules-as-written subculture. Some questions are about the middle that excludes. Questions about a game's text can be sufficiently tagged with **the system tag**. If the [raw] tags adds nothing more than [not-house-rules], it will inevitably be burninated as useless, likes [rules]. So don't exclude that middle if you're trying to defend the tag; its self-defeating.

Comment: @mxyzplk Let me make this clear: I totally agree that's what answers *should* be like. That they're *not* is why the site needs the tag (or one like it). I also agree reality should change (pesky reality), but it won't with the deletion of a tag. That's not flip: the site's to evolve with use, and while questions and answers can be *shaped*, legislating the hobby change its behavior *immediately* is too drastic a step. So few users means a question wanting a text-based answer yet getting a well-received corn-flakes epiphany may cause a good textual answer to be self-censored or downvoted.

Comment: @HeyICanChan But see, that doesn't make any sense.  All answers should be like that.  They're not.  So we should put on a tag to try to make them like that.  Then really we should put the tag on all the questions.  All = none, and the tag is therefore superfluous.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If we’re not going to start assuming that every rules question is from a rules-as-written perspective (which I’m fine with), doesn’t that *in itself* indicate the purpose of the tag: to indicate and categorize those questions that *are*?

Comment: @KRyan Well yes, that's why my answer here exists. I do recognise whatever it is that RAW represents distinctly from… everything else that doesn't have a catchy name. If I can see it, I would hope that Forrest and others here could also see that it is distinct and avoid claiming that every question about the game text is also about rules-as-written, and could articulate the tag's value in representing that distinct thing. This defense eclipsing mine in votes is not a good thing for you; this answer basically says [raw] is a synonym of [rules]. I would hope you could instead speak to its value.

Comment: Here's the thing that is baffling me about this, and previous assertions that *nobody* ever makes this mistake with the tag: why do you need evidence to believe something that seems so obvious and likely?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I’ve never said nobody does, I’ve said I haven’t seen any clear cases of it. It is obvious that it’s *possible*, but I do no think it is either obvious that it necessarily *does* and I do not think it is obvious that this is also necessarily *likely*. And can you not see how I might get defensive when I see comments that could be read as “a lot of people are using this tag, they couldn’t possibly all really want to be using it!” as an assumption? Some people in this discussion seem to be coming into it with the *a priori* assumption that only a very small minority wants it.

Comment: No, I don't understand why you would misinterpret this discussion that way in the first place, but once taken that way I suppose it's obvious you'd take it personally. Maybe taking it personally is a barrier to understanding what's going on here? The problem: a) people *do* type stuff into the tag bar and then use whatever shows up; we see that with misused tags all the time; b) people *do* try to find a [rules] tag; we know this from when there was a [rules] tag. Ergo, it is abundantly obvious that some (unknown) percentage of [rules-as-written] uses are mistaken. Is that not sensible?

Comment: To me the claim is not that its misused but that it's irrelevant.  Rules questions are answered the same with and without the tag.  Newest site rules question is http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74054/wild-shape-reversion-to-true-form.  It's answered with rules, as one would expect.  Adding the raw tag would change nothing. Adding or removing the tag to a wide array of questions makes no difference, therefore the tag itself is sick and is kinda clearly a meta tag in practice.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I've never disputed that in theory, but your unknown percentage is one that I assume is quite small, quite possibly neat zero. You will never convince me that it is appropriate to assume error in the absence of any evidence aside from its possibility. In fact, you'll never convince me that such an assumption is not extremely rude.

Comment: @mxyzplk when asking a question you do not know the answer to, one cannot know if the tag is necessarily relevant for that question. That doesn't make it meaningless or a meta tag: for some questions, it is relevant. Stating that, if relevant, RAW needs to be examined for what it is, is valid and is **not** part of the default operation of the site. And I know you don't want it to be.

Comment: 3 of 6 of the last RAW questions linked above clearly don't treat the question as "RAW only."  50% >> 0%.

Comment: @mxyzplk  Sample size doesn't pass the smell test.  Shalvenay's answer seems germane to me.

Comment: You don't find the fact that we have a setup where there is an unknowable percentage of questions being ***helped wrong*** inherently abhorrent? I'm sorry, but concerns that it might be presumptuous to second-guess are utterly irrelevant. If you actually cared about that, you would not defend a system that even allowed for such second-guessing. You would advocate for clear tags that prevented users who lack your rudeness concerns from needing to second-guess the tag's use. You want this issue to die? It won't die while it's considered a daily tagging problem.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is there any evidence that anyone is dissatisfied with the help they received? There are **8** RAW questions without an accepted answer, just over 1%. And is an undiscoverable tag using terminology that we have just made up ourselves a solution to this? You are assuming it’s a problem. Mxyzplk claims 3 of 6 are “clearly” not really RAW questions, except he uses that word a lot and he is self-identified biased. I am not going to accept the assumptions of people who don’t like the concept to begin with as reason to damage the usability of the site for a segment of the community.

Comment: Ok, this is getting a bit excessive. "If you actually cared [you'd agree with me]" is _not_ the way to do this, and neither is fixating on numbers we don't have. Yes, it is a problem when people confuse [rules-as-written] with [rules]. No, we don't know how often that happens. Is this being treated with bias? Maybe, but there are valid problems with [RAW] that have been brought up and still need to be addressed. They won't be if we keep going back and forth like this.

Comment: @Pixie I strongly believe that there is either no problem, or no problem significant enough warranting the changes being suggested. Hence the request for evidence, which, as you say, we clearly don’t have. Just assumptions.

Comment: That doesn't mean that a pretty logical explanation for at least some of the noise we're getting in [rules-as-written] isn't worth seriously considering and taking care of if possible (such as with a tag that is clearer, because RAW _is_ jargon). There are also other issues, and it seems that they aren't really getting attention because of quibbling over this. You're also capable of doing your own research. Go read the RAW tag and see for yourself how many of those ask for and accept anything but strictly RAW answers. That's what you're asking others to do, but, hey, it's right there.

Comment: @Pixie The burden of proof is on those who think there is a problem. No, I will not do their homework for them. The removal or renaming of the tag would have an effect on the site that I consider extremely deleterious, far more so than any alleged hypothetical noise. I read a lot of rules-as-written questions, and don’t see a problem myself; that is good enough for me.

Comment: No, KRyan. If you're going to give a nonsense reason for opposing renaming the tag, the burden of proof is on you to support the reason. “I feel like it might be insulting to some nameless people to even discuss this” has zero weight. Your unsubstantiated feeling in defense of nameless parties is orders of magnitude less important than making sure the site functions well. Especially when you've avowed that you don't understand tagging policy-theory; you're not going to obstruct sensible reforms with demagoguery: accusations of bias and unsupported statements of unfairness based on feeling.

Comment: You want to talk about bias? I hate with a burning passion the style of play espoused by the RAW community. And I am trying to **save the damned tag** because I care more about the site being inclusive and its tagging being useful and accurate that my inconsequential feelings about what the tag is tagging. How's that for bias, hm? So set your own aside, quit sabotaging your own interests, and work with me, dammit. Saying “I got mine, everyone else can STFU on the issue” is not acceptable from you anymore.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Really? You are suggesting outright obfuscation of the tag, literally making a concerted effort to make it undiscoverable, by design, and my objection is *nonsense*? My complaints that no *actual, demonstrated* problem has *ever* been offered by the critics is *nonsense*? An alleged could-maybe-be-a-problem-in-theory-but-who-knows-in-practice is such a massively serious concern that we should denigrate an entire segment of the community *just in case*, actual case-making and evidence-gathering can’t be done because this hypothetical is just *that serious*?

Comment: This isn't a problem in theory, it's been demonstrated. That you've chosen to ignore the demonstration doesn't make it not demonstrated. I have no wish to denigrate a segment of the community, nor to obfuscate the tag. (Do you think so little of the community that they can't find a tag named [raw], [strictly-raw], or somesuch? Really?) **My priority is that I am responsible to all members of the site.** If you want to say “I see no problem” and disclaim your responsibility as a high-rep user to step outside of your own concerns and work to make the site better, that is extremely disappointing.

Comment: And, may I add, extremely ill-chosen. You can disclaim responsibility to consider other viewpoints, but you don't have the power to make yours stick if you choose to do so. If you turn your nose up at discussion of the issue, you just won't be considered. I'll try to represent the tag's usefulness without your input.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Where is the demonstration? I requested a demonstration, and haven’t been pointed to any. The list in mxyzplk’s question is not a demonstration. There are 792 questions tagged rules-as-written, he has a list of six, and none of those looks like a mis-tagging to me. His reference to “slam dunk rules answer” as if that is a reason for rules-as-written to not be on a question makes no sense (by definition, the person asking didn’t know it would be a slam dunk when they tagged it). (cont’d)

Comment: @KRyan People should back up what they say, but that includes you as well, and when everyone has equal access to the same information, I think it's fair to expect that people will utilize it. Especially when they're trying to discuss and make claims about it. So, tell me: _have_ you given the content in the RAW tag a good, exhaustive look yet? If not, you need to do that. So does everybody else.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie  The tiny hut question shows a problem in *voting practices*, certainly; you don’t have to convince me that this is a problem, but it’s not a problem with the tag, IMO. And since no answer has been accepted yet, we do not yet have any information on the querent’s opinion there aside from the tag that they did put on the question.  The hostage one has accepted an answer that goes through the rules in a series of possiblities, and only at the end briefly challenges the frame with a houserule suggestion, which is entirely reasonable.

Comment: @Pixie Proving a negative is a fool’s errand. I read rules-as-written questions constantly; they’re one of my biggest interests on this site. Have I done a thorough *review*? No. But I also have been reading the questions as they come up. I am not just assuming there is no problem, I am stating that as someone who reads a lot of these questions, I have not seen substantial evidence of a significant problem

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If it makes you feel better, exactly why I don’t consider the list in the question to be the demonstration that you seem to claim it is has been added to my answer.

Comment: @KRyan I refer not to the list, I refer to our tagging history. I explained it in [this comment](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6055/the-rules-as-written-tag-still-useful-or-is-it-junk/6058?noredirect=1#comment17357_6058). I also read every [rules-as-written] question posted on the site: I read *every* question posted. If that is all you believe it takes to speak with final authority on the subject, then that very belief grants my view superiority to yours, by sheer numbers. Clearly that is nonsense, though. Don't you have any other support for your position?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie *Non sequitur.* There are a number of assumptions and logical leaps in your argument. First, you claim people “do” just pick things off the list of tags, but you have not supported that claim – and moreover, you have not supported it with numbers so we have a sense of how significant a problem we’re talking about. Second, you assume that someone who types “rules” sees rules-as-written and doesn’t stop to question that title, just selects it. And even if I stipulate that it does happen, *how much* is still important – because the proposed “solution” has costs too.

Comment: @KRyan Hm, that's right, you joined long after the fiasco with the [rules] tag. I guess you're not interested in anyone's Good Subjective experience that people have and do obviously type `rules` and grab whatever turns up (which you can also see today with other tags, if you watch for it). That's not really something you can *fruitfully* dispute though—that direct-observation knowledge will keep driving the attempt to resolve this problem. So then, in the interest of progress: this is the first I've heard of costs to renaming. I don't see them; can you articulate what they are?

Comment: @KRyan Proving negatives has nothing to do with this. If you'd researched, you'd know whether the proof you're looking for is there or not. You should be doing that _already_ in order to have a meaningful dialog on the subject; this is not doing someone else's homework. The points that defenders of the tag need to support are that the tag is being used correctly and usefully, that people are using it when they're asking for RAW content (as opposed to "RAW and/or house"), that people are actually getting that when they use the tag, etc. Also, as SSD requests, demonstrate why renaming is bad.

Comment: That said, @SevenSidedDie, that you care about the site and its users is important. But telling other users that they don't care/suggesting that you are doing a better job of this because you care _more_ is not constructive. It's uncharitable at the least. Maybe you disagree with their methods, but they wouldn't be engaging in this mess if they didn't care. I know I wouldn't.

Comment: @Pixie Yes, I am asserting a superior stance: I'm advocating compromise. KRyan is advocating no change, the others (the other mods and BESW, most notably) are advocating complete elimination of the tag. Something's gotta give, since this issue has been simmering for years. KRyan asserting insouciant immovability is either going to bend and seek compromise, or see that movement can happen without him. Since he's the foremost advocate for the tag, and I think he's right we need it but wrong that it must not be touched, ***yeah*** I'm trying to shake him out of his complacency to engage.

Comment: If non-RAW answers to RAW questions are 'a legitimate frame challenge' then to me that proves that the tag has zero meaning. The default answer to any question is the clear rule if there is one, common sense interpretation if there's some conflict or unclear, and tested table rulings if there's a larger gap.  Redefining these as OK for RAW questions eliminates any significant differential meaning for the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You're free to disagree and to persuade and to assert your stance as much as you want. Just do it _without_ passive aggressive, guilt-trippy tactics like telling people if they cared they would agree with you. You don't need to do that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, what you’re doing is turning a “is there a problem?” discussion into a “how do we address the problem that we’re tacitly assuming exists?” (On which point, I’m noticing a trend in how the moderation team approaches subjects it dislikes.) My suggestion that there is no evidence of misuse is still higher rated than any suggestion to *do anything*. Thus, you lack even a clear consensus *that there even is a problem,* much less that anything should be done about it.

Comment: It's a meta post in the [discussion] tag: discussions can range where they like on the subject and policy can result from that. And I see 6 to 5 now for two extremist positions: that's a community divided and not showing signs of consensus about the issue. Besides, you've already flatly stated there is no evidence possible you'd accept: anyone who classes a tagging as mistaken is, you say, imagining it, rude, biased, or all three.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Has there ever been a case where someone used the tag, and then through comments or otherwise, indicated that they were looking for houserules, and had the tag explained to them and then removed? Because that’s the kind of clear-cut case I would expect to justify a policy change that involves eliminating the rules-as-written segment of the community is stripped of its ability to have the tag named the thing that that community calls it. Because that’s a pretty basic courtesy afforded to every other segment of the community, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Please don't continue with the "superior stance" language. It doesn't help the discussion and comes off as self-serving. Compromise isn't inherently a superior position to take, sometimes it's a crap one that makes nobody happy. Recognise that as citizens of a place that's community-moderated, *we also* care about and feel responsible for the community, just like you.

Comment: Precisely. The problem is not that you feel you have a solution you need to argue for, SSD. It's taking aim at others. I could say, "If you cared about this site, you wouldn't have told others that they didn't." Would that be fair? Would it accomplish anything except putting you on the defensive about how much you do care? And @doppelgreener is right. Sometimes compromise fails entirely. It's fine if you believe that a compromise is better in this situation, but it's not better _just because_ it's a compromise or because you care a lot. We all do. It's not a question of that, so leave it out.

Comment: I have never flagged so many comments in a single thread as "rude or offensive" as I have this day. Everyone, I recommend keeping the conversation civil and assuming good faith on the part of those who disagree with you. And yes, current reader, I am talking to you right now, not just the people disagreeing with you.

Comment: The rudeness argument has no standing, KRyan (and is irredeemably subjective besides). Site functionality will trump that every time, because site functionality necessarily comes before caring about the functionality's effect on users' feelings. Tags gets named according to community usage preferentially, but where necessary we alter them to fix or avoid issues. This is normal practice and [rules-as-written] does not get special consideration just because some people would feel touching it at all would be persecution.

Comment: Two things are outstanding: what extremely detrimental effects would renaming have? I would like that articulated, so I can account for it. Currently I'm ignoring that as unsubstantiated, as extreme claims need at least modest support (argument or evidence). Second, I'd like to hear what you would count as evidence, which is what you're asking for. So far you've said that any claim that a [raw] tag has been misused can only be due to bias from the claimant—so what kind of evidence *would* you accept? Setting the bar at a logically impossible place is not useful.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Voting suggests that the site as a whole does not see a problem. The site as a whole acknowledges the value of the rules-as-written tag, and acknowledges that the problem of misuse is conceivable, but that the only proposed solution to it is a “desperate measure” that would only be appropriate *if* the problem could be substantiated as serious. The community does not currently consider it to be so substantiated. Convincing *me* is secondary to convincing *everyone*, and I cannot speak for everyone.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have stated previously the kind of evidence I would expect to see before making a change, however: cases where the rules-as-written tag was removed after author clarification that it was used in error. And a one-off example is not sufficient to indicate a pattern. I likewise cannot speak for everyone when describing why renaming would be considered “desperate,” but for myself, the significant, *by-design* decrease in discoverability, potential damage to SEO, and yes, the relegation of rules-as-written to second-class status all spring to mind immediately.

Comment: @KRyan Thank you. That kind of evidence can't be derived from existing questions (or would be prohibitive to), but that is useful to know for considering other methods of analysis.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Finally, let me state that I do not appreciate your continued attempts to dictate the terms of this discussion. They are not yours to dictate. You cannot move forward with any action without community support, and currently you clearly lack it.  You do not get to say that I don’t care about the site as a whole. You do not get to tell me that you’ll move forward without me unless I compromise—that is, give in to your essential premise that something is wrong to begin with. Collect evidence showing the problem you imagine is actually happening, or please stop bringing this up.

Comment: Regarding your concerns: Google is smart enough to map searches for `rules as written` to `raw`; people are smart enough to look for [raw] if [rules-as-written] doesn't exist; the decrease in discoverability is not by design nor existent (see previous “people aren't stupid” point), it is by design only to be less accidentally usable; and the idea that renaming a tag would be relegating it to second-class status is kinda bizzare, given the previous points, so I'm going to ignore that one.

Comment: Neither are they yours to dictate. We've had this discussion about that penchant of yours before. Note also that I upvoted BESW's second answer; because the parenthetical is only a parenthetical musing, it is not the answer itself, and you can't honestly say that that minor aside is what the votes are for.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I haven’t: I suggested that I did not see sufficient evidence to move forward with any change, and the community, at least with the present available evidence, seems to agree with me. I *suggested* terms; it is the community that is setting them as the actual terms. You’ll note I also do not claim to be final arbiter on what does and does not constitute sufficient evidence. And as for your claims about the effects of a renaming, the community seems to disagree with you there as well, so you’re going to have to do better than that to move forward.

Comment: The community doesn't want to burn the tag. That is all the votes currently show. (I'm glad; I agree.) Whether the community thinks renaming would be disastrous is not currently shown. Don't misread answers out of desperation.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie “I suspect that re-naming the tag would obfuscate the questions from experts almost as much, and should be considered a desperate measure,” is in BESW’s extremely-well-received post. It explicitly states that renaming “should be considered a desperate measure.” I am not misreading anything.

Comment: @KRyan Support for renaming is what would need to be shown (which is currently lukewarm), not whether the community is *worried* that renaming *might* be bad for unspecified reasons in a parenthetical that they *might* be agreeing with or *might* be ignoring when voting because it is a parenthetical musing rather than assertion.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a parenthetical musing or assertion. People voted for the post because it resonated with them, and who's to say what parts did and didn't? Things put in brackets don't magically get ignored for voting purposes; sometimes quite to the opposite they're even the thing that clinches someone's decision to vote. What _is_ the case is there's no strong support for renaming, and people have expressed concerns with doing so, and the top answers are presently advising against burning or there even being a problem.

Comment: @doppelgreener Oh, absolutely. No-one can say which part, except the main point, are what resonated. (Presumably no-one would upvote if they actively disagreed with the main point. Or maybe that's not something I should assume?) That “no-one” includes KRyan. I know that I upvoted it despite that parenthetical, so I know that his assertion that the upvotes all support the parenthetical is false.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Point of order, KRyan never asserted that all the upvotes all support the parenthetical. He said it's part of BESW's extremely well-received post, and that's it. The implication is that people support this post very well, with little disagreement, which makes it reasonable to infer that all parts of it are resonating at least decently, including the parenthetical. Also, calling it desperation is making the discussion _needlessly_ personal, and making totally unnecessary and distressing inferences about KRyan's behaviour and character.

Comment: @doppelgreener To be fair, KRyan has already stated that this is a matter of personal affront and a defensive, protective reaction to perceiving hostile intrusions on the part of the site he has staked a claim to. I don't need inferences when it's already public record, and a significant roadblock I perceive is that KRyan is evidently perceiving mundane site management as inherently personal. Since he has made his feelings a central issue of this conflict, they're unfortunately unignorable.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Having reread all of KRyan's comments above, I see no statement of personal affront here, beyond KRyan's assertion in his first comments that assuming everyone must be using RAW in error is rude (which is an assertion with some merit). Yes, KRyan may be defensive, we're talking about the potential destruction of a tag. I still consider it unnecessarily inflammatory and inappropriate to insinuate *desperation* in your opposition. It is not becoming of a moderator attempting to produce constructive discussion, and is in fact quite condescending.

Comment: @doppelgreener He said it in chat.

Answer (score 6):

Since there seems to be no consensus on anything other than the fact that we have very little data about any supposed issues with [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) because all the data is in comment discussions that are getting cleaned up -- I have an even more radical proposal to share:

## We put a hold on cleaning up comments on [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) questions and answers until this situation is firmly resolved.

This would allow us to aggregate the commentary that is being said to provide insight into this issue over space and time, and then analyze it as a *body of work* instead of as a few, disjointed examples notable only because of their recency.

Comment: Mods can already dig up this information if necessary, note. That's a lot of posts though.

Comment: If you can data dump it all into a spread sheet, I can spend a few sessions over coffee analyzing the information available.  (My email address I think you have via site info).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's unfortunately manual digging. :-/

Comment: Ok, that might need some quiet time on the weekend to look into.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Retrieving and analysing ~800 pages' comments is more like a couple weeks to a month of full workdays.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie As I understand the scope of work, it is find all questions with Rules As Written Tag, examine question and answers for adherence to that tag's avowed purpose, and plot them on a graph/tabulate them.  A second task is to get all deleted comments and check them for points and information related to the above.  Is that about right?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Not answers, just questi0ns. But yes, all comments (including on answers) that could shed light on the asker's meaning in using the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have identified 195 questions with the combined tags of 5e and rules as written.  I will be reviewing them one at a time and try to classify them.  Yes, it is more than a few cups of coffee.  But, with the Super bowl on and me being a multitasker, maybe I can make some progress.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie doppelgreener has identified a year's worth (a bit over a hundred) in the other meta, and that may give us the kind of sample size that becomes usable and large enough to guard against "spikey" occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

I do think we need a tag for the “let's play around with the literal interactions within this game”. It's significant enough as a playstyle, with its own particular issues and problems and needs, that it is often inherent to the subject of questions. And describing the core subject of questions is what tags are for.

The tag has value for those who invest in a RAW-centric way of playing *also* because it can be used to filter and highlight questions related to their expertise.

**However**, I do also think that it's being mistaken as a synonym for [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) by novice RPGers unfamiliar with the particular meaning that “rules as written” has for established RPGers. And we obviously get a lot of novice RPGers interested in D&D 5e.

I have a proposal to fix that problem then:
**Rename [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) so that it doesn't contain the substring `rules`, and don't make [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) a synonym.** This will ensure that it's not used by those who are just looking for “the rules tag.”

The only downside is that, without a synonym containing the substring `rules` it becomes less discoverable. However, someone who *deliberately* wants answers that approach the question RAW-centrically will either find the correct tag, or failing that will declare this need in their question. Either way, questions truly *about* RAW will be explicitly so. We have enough tags that aren't discoverable without hanging around the site for a while that it's really not a problem to rename it to solve the “rules tag” problem.

Comment: This may be pedantic, but I may be missing something important that you're implying: I don't think RAW is a playstyle; I consider it a critical lens for interpreting a document, not a set of practices and goals for play. By my thinking, calling it a playstyle weakens your argument: would we tag something [kick-in-the-door]?

Comment: @BESW Perhaps not a playstyle itself, but a core element of a certain playstyle then? I am at the particular disadvantage here of representing something I have only observed, not experienced, since this way of playing is antithetical to how I play. I expect KRyan, Hey I Can Chan, and a few other regulars may be able to speak more to its status as a playstyle.

Comment: I don't know about that - I think plenty of people who say "RAW" aren't really sure what it means - that was certainly true for RAI in our recent roundup on that.  Maybe if we had something not using a buzzword ([literal-reading-of-the-rules-only])?  At this point I kinda feel like "I want a literal interpretation only," like "Only books allowed are PHB and APG", are best added as real words clarifying in the question instead of trying to shortcut it with a "commonly understood" term that ends up not being commonly understood.

Comment: @mxyzplk That could be, yeah. *Personally* I would not miss the tag, but I think a “keep” option that also mostly solves the immediate problem (people looking for a [rules] tag) is good to have for voting purposes. (We might still have a problem with people *meaning* to use a RAW tag and misunderstanding the concept, but I think that's a smaller set that wouldn't rise to the level of site-management headache.)

Comment: I don't think obfuscating the name will do desirable stuff. We can't keep it a special secret if it's used regularly on public questions: people will still see it used, try to learn about it, misunderstand and misuse it, just maybe less than before. OTOH, if we successfully make it an obfuscated secret, isn't that bad? The whole site will still see [raw] questions, and those not in the know will give non-RAW answers and be punished for it: "-1 Didn't you see the [raw] tag?" "Uh, I guess, what's that mean?" We'd just have to write "I want rules as written" in the question like BESW says.

Comment: Alternately, since so few people on the site understand that [raw] should mean the answers should be rules-as-written, the not-in-the-know-crowd (the majority) completely ignores the tag and upvotes the non-RAW answers and the tag becomes ineffectual.

Comment: A name change isn't a bad idea, but for reasons others have noted, I wouldn't go with [raw]. I'd suggest something along the lines of [strict-rules-interpretation], [strict-text-interpretation], [literal-rules-interpretation], or [literal-text-interpretation]. I think those are clear but less likely to be confused with just [rules].

Comment: The problem is that the only alternative is [house-rules] which, unfortunately, connotes *not* playing by the rules and just making up stuff and is often leveled as an accusation. I'd be content with a tag synonym (although I don't think it necessary), but as @Pixie notes, a so-called secret tag seems needlessly obtuse. Maybe something a little more pleasant like [by-the-book] or [just-the-facts]?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hum? The main alternative isn't [house-rules], it's just not using a tag. Just like we don't require every question to have a system tag of some kind or [system-agnostic], we don't require every question to flag its relationship to the rules. The no-tag default is “not strict-RAW-focused, but not houseruling either”.

Comment: @Pixie I like your suggested alternative names. The aim of renaming is less “hide it from the noobs” and more to make its meaning less likely to be mistaken. I proposed moving it to [raw] because that's a unique terms that needs to be sought deliberately, but a tag name that is just more descriptively clear is even better for this aim, I think.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie *I* know that, but the *newcomer* doesn't know that, which is why having *nothing* appear automatically when typing in *rules* to tag a question would be better than [rule-as-written] coming up as the apparently best--and maybe only--option. In other words, I'm *agreeing* with you about most of this, but I reject a secret tag.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Cool, I understand what you're getting at. And I think I agree that a kinda-secret tag is less desirable, now that Pixie's given nicer suggestions than [raw].

Comment: Some small revisions  based on these comments.

Comment: @Pixie I was going to add your suggestions to the answer, but unfortunately they're all longer than our 25-character limit for tag names. Any other ideas?

Comment: This discussion reminds me that I should, at some point, write a main-site Q&A on what RAW is and isn’t and why anyone cares about it. I said I might do so the last time this discussion came up, but never got around to it. It still seems like a thing of value. Unless, @HeyICanChan, you want to take up that torch?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Hmm. [strict-text-reading] is under 25. It doesn't sound as good, though. [strict-interpretation] or [literal-interpretation] also work, but those aren't as clear. I'll comment again if I can think of anything better.

Comment: @KRyan sounds like a great idea - you could even go the whole hog and cover RAI as well :)

Comment: @KRyan That would be amazing, especially if, as Wibbs suggested, you also help clear up the issue where people use "RAI" to mean "what I think" rather than actually citing proof of how the rules were intended to be used.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it absolutely is a playstyle, and it's the only way to go unless you like constant arguments. When I play games, I don't want to have arguments over how realistic it is for helicopters to fly, or lasers to make things cold, or for rogues to disable spells. The book says it works that way, can we please just get on with pretending to be oddly cooperative murder-elves? Sure, the results are sometimes a little silly but that's a very small price, and it usually leads to fun results anyway.

Comment: @KRyan If you'd compose that Q&A it would be helpful.  Will be willing to act as proofreader/reviewer if you'd like.  Sometimes a second set of eyes helps.

Comment: @fectin It's certainly not the only way to go. (That belief is half our site's problem around this tag. (The *other* half is the belief that the only way to go is anti-RAW!)) But I agree it's a playstyle.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I might have some hyperbole in there. But you asked earlier for someone to present a defense of RAW as an actual playstyle, and I was happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0):

I think generically having a Rules-As-Written tag makes sense, but I don't think it makes sense to try to insist it mean a specific thing or warrant heavy moderation or deletion of answers.

That is, if it were my site, the tag would just indicate the question is about the rules as written, and would prefer answers in that context.

One of the main reasons I tend to avoid participating in this site very much, is what seems to me like excessive negativity and limiting of discussions for reasons I feel often limits the usefulness of the site even if the intention is to make the content better.

So personally I'd keep the tag but go light on the moderation and downvoting of interesting answers that have non-RAW content.

Comment: Moderation isn't about "making people do the rules!"  It's about making the site run smoothly.  I've personally participated in a number of questions, predominantly new users asking 5e questions, where they don't understand which they should be asking for (either using the RAW tag and then not wanting RAW, or conversely not using it and then complaining about non-RAW) or which to answer.  All we want is to either define the tag in a way that helps people or eliminate it, but if we have the tag and questions and answers with it aren't different from ones without it, it's pointless overhead.

Comment: @mxyzplk Seems to me new users won't likely read, or correctly use, or adhere to tag descriptions. That leaves not expecting them to, or a chore to make corrections, and I'd think the correction to make would be to add or remove the RAW tag after it's clear what fits. But, that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Dronz That's generally what we've been doing when it's obvious. However, there is also resistance to asking askers for clarification about what they mean when it's not obvious why they used the tag. Generally, there's resistance to questioning the tag's use, which makes the tag hard to manage and has lead us here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ah, I see. I don't envy you guys that task. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

[Addendum at the start: In the last few days the overall conversation has moved me toward a more moderate position on this tag's role--specifically [I've been convinced of the tag's value in directing experts to their field of specialty, which makes me interested in seeking a less extreme fate for the tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6066/4398). I will not delete this post however, as it is representing an option and argument that is important to have present in the discussion.]

Yes, **the RAW tag is turning into noise**, and its signal was never very strong to begin with.

RAW's never been a very useful tag for search-ability, or for connecting experts to questions in their field. The intent the tag is used to convey is just as easily communicated through writing "I'm interested in the written rules with as little interpretation as possible" or something similar in the body of the question.

Looking at RAW questions on the site (including the ones Mxy links above), often the accepted answer deals with intent and best practices. That means many querents who request RAW are also okay with less stringent answers, and the citizens who enforce the tag tend to not be the querents themselves. This indicates to me that in this instance a tag isn't the right tool for indicating the kind of answer you want to get.

Additionally, I've seen some debate over exactly what "rules as written" means outside of the tag use, with some folks feeling that it's actually impossible to entirely avoid interpretation of rules and so the phrase is just a matter of subjective degrees of what interpretations are "acceptable" or "unavoidable." Having querents put their request as a full sentence in the question text will help mitigate this kind of confusion.

If the problem with the tag is simply that new citizens don't know how to use it--well, we aren't consistently enforcing the proper use, which implies citizens who know about it don't care.

Whatever the cause of the tag's decline into noise, I'm not seeing it as a big loss. **Put the poor thing out of its misery.**

Comment: "Going by experience on the site, most querents who request RAW are also okay with less stringent answers and the citizens who enforce the tag tend to not be the querents themselves; this indicates to me that in this instance a tag isn't the right tool for indicating the kind of answer you want to get." **[Citation Needed]** This is asserted without evidence every single time this discussion happens, it is the **only** complaint ever leveled and it is **never** backed up.

Comment: @KRyan It is very difficult to show this *happening* because it's something that happens in comments which get deleted afterward. But we can easily see the effect: A quick glance across the site, including the examples Mxy provides in the question, shows accepted answers which hinge on intent. If the RAW tag were being used to mean "only RAW please," querents wouldn't be accepting RAI-focused answers.

Comment: My problem with this answer, though well stated, is that people asking questions often don't know if there's a rule, or a combination of rules in different volumes that will answer the question.  (My question about paladins and their mounts and smite spells is one such: I wasn't sure at that point if an interaction of multiple rules statements would change my understanding of how a mechanic works).  I thus cannot find fault in people asking questions with "unknown unknowns."  Not as bad in 5e D&D, but in games with lots of of  books ... "Do the rules cover this?" is a valid opening position.

Comment: Your addendum at the beginning resonates with me. I'm not keen on destroying the tag. (And, well, last time I didn't vote on a large policy discussion, I got burned hard for it, and I'm still not okay with how all of that went down.) So, -1 to this post as a vote against removing the tag.

Answer (score -6):

### TL;DR -- Figure out what to do with existing uses of [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written), then burninate/ban the tag, replacing it with a better tag -- likely [by-the-book](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by-the-book)

This is a case of people who don't understand how the tag is intended to function -- i.e. splitting:

- A question about the rules that can be safely answered by a per-table house-rule or even an on-the-spot DM ruling (the "hey, this rule is broken, lets toss it and replace it with something else" answer), or is an "obvious case" -- we *will* get "obvious case" questions, especially for the larger systems out there, because there's simply so much material that people will not have run across something before and not know where to find it

from

- A question about the rules that is seeking the rule itself to be interpreted, irrespective of how stupid it may be in anyone's eyes

The new users on this site aren't grasping this difference, and thinking that [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is a synonym for [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules).  Pixie's [suggested synonym](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6055/the-rules-as-written-tag-still-useful-or-is-it-junk#comment17310_6057) of [strict-rules-interpretation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strict-rules-interpretation) is a reasonable one, although I personally prefer Hey I Can Chan's [suggestion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6055/the-rules-as-written-tag-still-useful-or-is-it-junk#comment17313_6057) of [by-the-book](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by-the-book).

While both suggestions disentangle the tag from the RAW vs. RAI debate, I feel that [by-the-book](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/by-the-book) is an easier to grasp name for a newcomer -- this is the tag you use when you want a "by the book" answer to your question.  On the other hand, Pixie's [strict-rules-interpretation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strict-rules-interpretation) seems long, and slightly obtuse, in addition to risking more misuse from newbies who see the word "rules" in it and go "oh, this tag is for rules questions" when it really isn't, just like [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) isn't for straightforward rules questions *or* questions where RAI, rulings, and houserules are OK answers.

I'll leave the problem of what to do with the existing uses of [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) up to you folks, though -- I'm not fully versed in how Stack tags work.

(Also: the intent of [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is *not* an issue -- SO has [language-lawyer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) for similar reasons, and it has not given them this much grief as far as I can tell!  This is most likely because the SO [language-lawyer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) is derived from a term the community generally agrees upon the meaning of, instead of having a Stack-specific meaning, though.)

Comment: Actually, [rules-lawyer] would be the parallel tag/term that's in common RPG usage. We removed it in the past but maybe it's a better choice as it indicates that more by the book approach.

Comment: [Here's the discussion on the rules-lawyer removal](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5034/1204). It also had some very minor usage in social questions saying "someone's being a rules lawyer, what do I do". I'll note however that rules lawyering isn't strictly analogous - I've seen it used mostly as a pejorative term to describe bad behaviours that bring the game down, like someone who'd look at your awesome homebrew boss and and go "what!? that's not in the books, you can't do that, how dare you." (Even RAW players could find that awesome.) That would make it inappropriate for a RAW tag.